# Values of disabled inputs will not be submitted

Tags: form-submit, disabled-input, forms, http-post

This is what I found by Firebug in Firefox.

```
Values of disabled inputs will not be submitted
```

Is it the same in other browsers?

If so, what's the reason for this?

Comment: You can set a 'readonly' attribute. Chrome for example renders it as a disabled field but does submit it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disabled form inputs do not appear in the request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7357256/disabled-form-inputs-do-not-appear-in-the-request)

Answer (score 224, accepted):

Yes, *all* browsers should not submit the disabled inputs, as they are read-only.

[More information](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#disabled) (section 17.12.1)

> #### **Attribute definitions**
>
> disabled [CI] When set for a form control, this Boolean attribute
> disables the control for user input. When set, the disabled attribute
> has the following effects on an element:
>
> - Disabled controls do not receive focus.
> - Disabled controls are skipped in tabbing navigation.
> - Disabled controls cannot be successful.
>
> The following elements support the disabled attribute: BUTTON, INPUT,
> OPTGROUP, OPTION, SELECT, and TEXTAREA.
>
> This attribute is inherited but local declarations override the
> inherited value.
>
> How disabled elements are rendered depends on the user agent. For
> example, some user agents "gray out" disabled menu items, button
> labels, etc.
>
> In this example, the INPUT element is disabled. Therefore, it cannot
> receive user input **nor will its value be submitted with the form**.
>
> ```
> <INPUT disabled name="fred" value="stone">
> ```
>
> Note. The only way to modify dynamically the value of the disabled
> attribute is through a script.

Comment: Workaround: add an `<input type="hidden">` element with the same name/value as the disabled input.

Comment: any info on which browser does and which doesn't obey ?

Comment: use readonly="readonly" instead :) see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7357256/disabled-form-inputs-do-not-appear-in-request

Comment: @Allisone: Firefox & Chrome seem to obey this (disabled input are NOT submitted). Havn't tried on other browsers.

Comment: @JohnKugelman why the same name? the disabled one won't be submitted anyway.. may as well give the true name to the hidden one and use a different one for the disabled one

Answer (score 391):

`disabled` input will not submit data.

Use the `readonly` attribute:

```
<input type="text" name="inputName" readonly />
```

[Source here](http://blog.netgloo.com/2014/05/31/disabling-an-input-field-in-a-form-and-sending-data/)

Comment: @FrankFang, Ok, but, when I'm passing data to Laravel collective's blade template. It won't work. cannot send data like that way.

Comment: @ssi-anik `readonly` works, just make sure you pass "name" attr to the input.

Comment: Is `readonly` an accepted standard? According to [developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/readonly](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/readonly) doesn't look like it.

Comment: I don't get the point of having readonly only for inputs and textareas... How am I supposed to "disable" a select but still send the value via form submit?

Comment: @Masiorama the method of choice in these cases is set `<select name="mysel" disabled>[...]</select>` and add `<input type="hidden" name="mysel" value="_value_of_select_">`. Same name is not an issue as the select won't be submitted. As for the value the hidden one is sent, and it's ok since select is readonly so you know the select value beforehand. Select, checkbox, radio, ... don't have readonly as it prevents changing value, but they don't change value, rather `selected`, `checked`, etc. properties.

Comment: @NikiRomagnoli thanks for the reply. I kinda dislike the approach which imply 2 different inputs with the  same name, but I guess it is a good workaround. Will try it, though, thanks!

Answer (score 42):

You can use three things to mimic disabled:

1. HTML: `readonly` attribute (so that the value present in input can be used on form submission. Also the user can't change the input value)
2. CSS:  `'pointer-events':'none'` (blocking the user from clicking the input)
3. HTML: `tabindex="-1"` (blocking the user to navigate to the input from the keyboard)

Answer (score 25):

They don't get submitted, because [that's what it says in the W3C specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#successful-controls).

> 17.13.2 Successful controls
>
> A successful control is "valid" for submission. [snip]
>
> - Controls that are disabled cannot be successful.

In other words, the specification says that controls that are disabled are considered invalid for submission.

Answer (score 12):

```
<input type="text" disabled />
```

instead of this disabled use readonly

```
<input type="text" readonly />
```

Answer (score 8):

There are two attributes, namely `readonly` and `disabled`, that can make a semi-read-only input. But there is a tiny difference between them.

```
<input type="text" readonly />
<input type="text" disabled />
```

- The `readonly` attribute makes your input text disabled, and users are not able to change it anymore.
- Not only will the `disabled` attribute make your input-text **disabled**(unchangeable) but also **cannot it be submitted**.

jQuery approach (1):

```
$("#inputID").prop("readonly", true);
$("#inputID").prop("disabled", true);
```

jQuery approach (2):

```
$("#inputID").attr("readonly","readonly");
$("#inputID").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

JavaScript approach:

```
document.getElementById("inputID").readOnly = true;
document.getElementById("inputID").disabled = true;
```

PS `disabled` and `readonly` are standard html attributes. `prop` introduced with `jQuery 1.6`.

Answer (score 2):

`Disabled` controls cannot be successful, and a successful control is "valid" for submission.
This is the reason why disabled controls don't submit with the form.

Answer (score 1):

select controls are still clickable even on readonly attrib

if you want to still disable the control but you want its value posted.
You might consider creating a hidden field. with the same value as your control.

then create a jquery, on select change

```
$('#your_select_id').change(function () {
    $('#your_hidden_selectid').val($('#your_select_id').val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the Solution and still using disabled property.
First disable your inputs on load.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("formselector:input").prop("disabled",true);
  $( "formselector" ).submit(function( event ) {
      $(":disabled").prop("disabled",false);
      });
});
```

on submit enable all of them. this will assure everything is posted