# Bootstrap: Using a disabled button as a form input

Tags: php, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap, input

There may be a better way to do this, but I'm trying to create a button group where the left and right buttons are increment/decrement, and the middle button is a disabled button representing the value.

The field properly increments/decrements, but the value isn't getting passed to php.

I do like how the button group looks:

[image]

HTML

```
<form method="POST" action="send_email.php">
<div class="row"">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
        <h5><b>Attendees</b></h5>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
        <div class="btn-group">
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" name="decrease" value="-" onclick="decreaseBtnOnclick('attendees')"/>
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" name="attendees" value="0" id="chairs" disabled/>
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" name="increase" value="+" onclick="increaseBtnOnclick('attendees')"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="text-right">  
    <input type="hidden" name="email" value="contact">  
    <a href="./index.php">
        <button type="submit" class="btn-main">Finish!</button>
    </a>
</div>
</form>
```

Javascript (works fine to change the value in the middle button)

```
<script>
function increaseBtnOnclick(item) {
    document.getElementById(item).value = Number(document.getElementById(item).value) + 1;
}
function decreaseBtnOnclick(item) {
    if(document.getElementById(item).value > 0){
        document.getElementById(item).value = Number(document.getElementById(item).value) - 1;
    }
}
```

PHP (works fine for other types of inputs, e.g., text)

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) { 
    $attendees = $_POST['attendees']; // required
    echo "Attendees: ".$attendees;
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a hidden input then add the value of your disabled button to it with JS.

JS

```
function increaseBtnOnclick(item) {
    var newValue = Number(document.getElementById(item).value) + 1;
    document.getElementById(item).value = newValue;
    document.getElementById("hidden_input").value = newValue;
}
function decreaseBtnOnclick(item) {
    if(document.getElementById(item).value > 0){
    var newValue = Number(document.getElementById(item).value) - 1;
        document.getElementById(item).value = newValue;
        document.getElementById("hidden_input").value = newValue;
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<form method="POST" action="send_email.php">
<div class="row"">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
        <h5><b>Attendees</b></h5>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
        <div class="btn-group">
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" name="decrease" value="-" onclick="decreaseBtnOnclick('attendees')"/>
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" name="attendees" value="0" id="chairs" disabled/>
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" name="increase" value="+" onclick="increaseBtnOnclick('attendees')"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="hiddenvalue" id="hidden_input" value="0">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="text-right">  
    <input type="hidden" name="email" value="contact">  
    <a href="./index.php">
        <button type="submit" class="btn-main">Finish!</button>
    </a>
</div>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) { 
    $attendees = $_POST['hiddenvalue']; // required
    echo "Attendees: ".$attendees;
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could switch to a regular input field with [button addons](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-buttons).

Answer (score 0):

Disabled input fields do not get posted, however you can set it to readonly.

Please have a look at this thread,

[Disabled form inputs do not appear in the request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7357256/disabled-form-inputs-do-not-appear-in-request)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a hidden input field:

```
<input type="hidden" id="h_attendees" name="h_attendees" value="0"/>
```

In your increaseBtnOnclick and decreaseBtnOnclick you could set the value of the hidden field.

```
function increaseBtnOnclick(item) {
    document.getElementById(item).value = Number(document.getElementById(item).value) + 1;
    document.getElementById("h_attendees").value = document.getElementById(item).value;
}
function decreaseBtnOnclick(item) {
    if(document.getElementById(item).value > 0){
        document.getElementById(item).value = Number(document.getElementById(item).value) - 1;
        document.getElementById("h_attendees").value = document.getElementById(item).value;
    }
}
```

And access it in PHP

```
$_POST['h_attendees'];
```