# Send specific input to another page

Tags: php, html, input

Hello I have many inputs `radiobutton` but i don't need to send them all to my insert php. How can I choose some input and send it to another page with one button ?

MY code is very long

something like this x7

This is my autocomplete page

```
<!-- fonction doubler la rangꥠdu dimanche -->   

<div >
    <form method="post"  >
        <div id="itemRows">
            <?php
            if ($result != false && mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                while ($product = mysqli_fetch_array($result)):
                    ?>
                    <p id="oldRow<?= $product['id'] ?>">    <input type="text" name="client1<?= $product['id'] ?>" size="4" value="<?= $product['client1'] ?>" />   <input type="text" name="name<?= $product['id'] ?>" value="<?= $product['name'] ?>" />  </p>
                <?php
                endwhile;
            }
            ?>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
</td>

<!-- client du dimanche -->
<td>
    <span id="proclient">   
        <input type="text" name="client1" size="12" class = "client1"  id ="client1" disabled />    
    </span>
</td>
<!-- description du projet de dimanche -->
<td>
    <span id="prodesc">
        <input type="text" name="desc1" size="30" id ="desc1" class "desc" disabled />
    </span>
</td>
<!-- ddescription de la tache du dimanche -->
<td>
    <span id="protache">
        <textarea rows="1" cols="20" name="taskDesc1" id ="task1" class "task"> </textarea>
    </span>
</td>
<!-- lieu pour dimanche -->
<td>
    <span id="prolieu">
        <input type="text" name="prolieu1" size="10" id ="lieu1" class "lieu">
    </span> 
</td>   

<!-- tache  -->     
<td>
    <span id="tache">
    <!--    <input type="text"  name="tache" size="30" id="tache"class= "tache"  />  -->    
        <!-- dꣵt section combobox tache avec tool tip -->                   
        <label title="Select your state"> <select title="Select your state" id="state" name="state">
                <?php
                $stmt->execute();
                while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                    echo ' <option title="';
                    echo $row['tacName'];
                    echo '">';
                    echo $row['tacId'];
                    echo '</option>' . "\n";
                    $task = array();
                }
                ?>
            </select>
        </label>
        <!-- Fin section cobobox tache avec tool tip -->        
    </span>
</td>

<!-- calculter le temps pour le diamnche -->        
<td>
    <span id="calculTemps">
        <input type="number" id="input1"  class="temps"  name="tempsdi" size="10" min="0" max="24" value="0"/><br/>
    </span>
</td>
<br>
```

like I said i don' need to send all value of the input, how do I choose the one I need?

**EDIT** Here is theinsert php, I want to take some VAR from my autocomplete cause I will insert them to the database afterwards.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="fr">
    <LINK rel=stylesheet type="text/css" href="main.css">




    <?php

    session_start(); 
    $client1 = $_POST['client1'] ;
// Connect to the DB
    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","cruel") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link));


    // adding new recherche
    if(!empty($_POST['name'])) 
    {
        foreach($_POST['name'] as $name)
        {
        // THIS IS NOTÉ FINISH MY INSERT AND NEED TO BE MODIFY LATER

            $sql = "INSERT INTO recherche (name) VALUES ('".mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$name)."')";
            $link->query($sql);
        }
    } 


$date = $_POST['data'] ;


echo($client1);
echo($date);




?>
```

Comment: why would you prevent sending them all? just do it and pick the one you need...

Comment: cause i will save them in a database and i don't them all

Comment: you can still select the ones you want to save, unless your code to do it just includes all at once (not a good practice I'd say)...

Comment: how do i choose the one i want to send in my insert php?

Comment: see my response to that below... but what I suggested first, was rather to modify your "insert php" to add fields selectively... you know that you can get them like this: `$_POST['some_field_name']`, once the form is submitted, right?

Comment: i tried but is said error Undefined index: client1 if I tried to send by a form and take it like this  $client1= $_POST['client1'] ;

Comment: well, looking at your code, you do not have `client1` inside your `form` tags, you only have `name="client1<?= $product['id'] ?>"` which would be equivalent to something like `client11` or `client12`... depending on the output of `$product['id']`...

Comment: the line you mention is my autocomplete here is my line of my client1

<input type="text" name="client1" size="12" class = "client1"  id ="client1" disabled />

Comment: Yes, but it's OUTSIDE a `form` tag. If you want to send something, it has to be INSIDE the `form` tags with the opening `form` having `action=`... [your insert php]

Comment: can you give me an exemple with my code?

Comment: I'll update my answer in a sec...

Answer (score 0):

The `<form>` and `</form>` tag determines which inputs will be sent to the server, being every input tag between those tags. If you want to send only a selection of inputs you can create multiple HTML forms on a single page. You'll need a submit button in every one though, and form tags cannot be nested in other form tags.

Comment: i don't want multiple button just one named finish and send exemple my monday client my friday project etc.

Comment: How will the submit button then 'know' which form to send?

Comment: i don'T know that why i need help

Answer (score 0):

Any input that has a `name` attribute will be sent. If you don't want to send a specific input, just make sure it has no `name` attribute and ensure those that are needed do have one.

**EDITED:** Following some comments to the original post, and my answer and your updated code, here is what I propose.

Your problem is **not only** with the fact that you cannot selectively send something to your "insert php" but the fact that you're actually not sending anything it correctly.

First of all, make sure your `form` attributes wrap all the fields that you **do** want to send, ie. anything below `<!-- client du dimanche -->` is not currently sent as they are **outside** the `form` tags.

Second, on your "insert php", doing `foreach($_POST['name'] as $name)` won't work as `foreach` is there to iterate over arrays, but `$_POST['name']` is going to output a value of the array `$_POST`, thus your `foreach` loop will most probably fail. Nonetheless you don't even have an input on your original page with `name=name` so you're looking for the wrong one and I believe you just don't necessarily understand the difference between *attributes* and *indexes*.

So let me explain: the `name` part on an input field is an *attribute*, whatever it has as a value will become the *index* of the array `$_POST` on the page you're sending the form to. In your example, provided (and **only if**) you do wrap those other inputs **inside** your form tags, `client1`, `desc1`... will become *indexes* of `$_POST`, like this: `$_POST['client1']` for example.

I believe what you're trying to achieve is a little more complicated and is not in the scope of this question, so all I can recommend you to do is to lookup some basic tutorials on mysqli and follow them. One of such could be http://codular.com/php-mysqli.

Comment: I think if you add the disabled attribute, on the fly, it will have the same effect

Comment: diasabled cause i have a autocomplete function. and do you have a exemple if i just want to send exemple my client, project but no other thing?

Comment: @py_script Why don't you add it as a response? it's also a possible one!

Comment: @TheBaconManWithouBacon Do you mean your autocomplete function needs the `name` attribute? if so, you might as well go with disabling the ones that you don't need, as @py_script suggested.

Comment: my autocomplete with ID and enter pressed.

Comment: I'm guessing that the inputs will point to other functionality which is why you need them without being sent to the db, so disabling them would not be an option, correct? ok, so did you try simply removing their `name` attribute?

Comment: If I remove their name i could send the one I want to insert.php?

Comment: remove `name` = will NOT be sent --- keep `name` = WILL be sent ;)

Comment: I understand the diffence of a index or attribute. I just don't understand how could I send witch I need . If i could send all input with a specific tag.

Comment: and what is the link of mysqi? I'm not talking of my database for the moment I know how to do it

Comment: @TheBaconManWithouBacon I don't think your question was about how to send data to the DB via MySQLi, correct? well, the problem is that you're doing it incorrectly, as detailed in my answer... try fixing it following my instructions and add a new question if you're stuck...

Comment: I said as comment mysqli was not finish i didn't fix it and didn't work it for the moment my only question was how do i send 4 of my 50 input to insert.php so after i'll work mysqli. So I don't know why for the moment you're talking of mysqi if that was not my question

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you add the disabled attribute, on the fly, to the fields you do not want to include on the request, it will have the desired effect.

For example:

```
document.getElementById("my_target_element").disabled = true;
```

There is a similar question here, where the OP, doesn't want that effect. Worth taking a look

[Disabled form inputs do not appear in the request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7357256/disabled-form-inputs-do-not-appear-in-request)

Hope it helps...