# Ruby on Rails: display:none doesn't eliminate unwanted values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a form with where there's two different `select` tags but has the same object name. These `select` tags are hidden and is shown only dependent on certain values from another `select` tag.

```
<%= f.select :gender, gender %> <!-- gender has Men and Women values -->

<div id="womens" style="display:none;">
  <%= f.select :service, women %>
</div>

<div id="mens" style="display:none;">
  <%= f.select :service, men %>
</div>
```

So there are different services in each women and men select. This is my jQuery

```
jQuery ->
  $("#gender").change ->
    genderValue = $("#gender option:selected").attr("value")
    if genderValue == "Women"
      $("#womens").show()
      $("#mens").hide()
    else if genderValue == "Men"
      $("#mens").show()
      $("#womens").hide()
    else
      $("#womens").hide()
      $("#mens").hide()
```

I've noticed that when I choose a value for `mens` to show up, it will only save anything that is still in the `womens` select tag. How do I make it so when its hidden, its really hidden and my submit form won't want to get values from the true hidden fields.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try to disable the form element:

```
$("#mens select").prop('disabled', true);
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem you've got is [`display: none`](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp) literally just hides the element

JS doesn't care about what things *look* like; it just takes the DOM with the elements loaded on screen. I would personally use Ajax to make this flexible & secure, but as `Stefan` has already recommended, disabling the element will work

> [Disabled form inputs do not appear in the request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7357256/disabled-form-inputs-do-not-appear-in-request)