# Why does 'disabled' cause problems when e-mailing contact forms?

Tags: php, email

I have an input in a contact form to record the users IP address:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="ip" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; ?>" disabled>
```

This works ok. It shows the users IP address when they are completing the contact form.

The problem is including this in the e-mail.

I am including it in the e-mail using:

```
  $ip = $_POST['ip'];
```

but it generates this error message on send:

```
Notice: Undefined index: ip in /var/www/contact.php on line 51
```

I don't get this error message with any other inputs so I assume it is to do with using `disabled` in the form?

Comment: Take a look at [Disabled form inputs do not appear in request](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7357256/908174). Voting to close as duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

disabled doesn't cause this error, two things you should do: 1. check your website is validated using the W3C validator. 2. Try using 'readonly' instead of 'disabled' see what happens
EDIT:
 1. check for meta charset, use utf-8 is it's alright.

EDIT 2: Please note that `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];` does not always resolve the client's ip address.

Comment: `readonly` makes it work. Why do all online references say to use this `disabled`? Thanks I'll accept when it allows.

Comment: You can find more info @ http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#disabled

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `disabled`.

Do this instead:

```
<input type="hidden" name="ip" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; ?>">
```

Because `disabled` means the value of that field isn't sent when the form is submitted.

Answer (score 0):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input):

> ... a disabled control's value isn't submitted with the form.

You can solve this using `readonly` instead.