# How do i pass this POST data?

Tags: javascript, html

I am having some trouble passing this info from a dropdown form.

First of all I have one dropdown, and when you choose A, B or C, a `DIV` shows with another dropdown for either, A, B or C.

The dropdown in these `DIV` are all 3 named product.

Here I have the code which want to show `DIV`:

```
<script>
    function namedata(data) {
        if (data == 'AA') {
            $('#divaa').css('display', 'block');
            $('#divb').css('display', 'none');
            $('#divc').css('display', 'none');
            $('#diva').css('display', 'none');

        }
        if (data == 'A') {
            $('#diva').css('display', 'block');
            $('#divb').css('display', 'none');
            $('#divc').css('display', 'none');
            $('#divaa').css('display', 'none');


        }
        else if (data == 'B') {
            $('#divb').css('display', 'block');
            $('#diva').css('display', 'none');
            $('#divc').css('display', 'none');
            $('#divaa').css('display', 'none');

        }
        else if (data == 'C') {
            $('#divc').css('display', 'block');
            $('#diva').css('display', 'none');
            $('#divb').css('display', 'none');
            $('#divaa').css('display', 'none');

        }
    }
</script>
```

And here i have all the dropdowns

```
<select name="name" onchange="return namedata(this.value);">
    <option value="AA">PLEASE CHOOSE</option>
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
</select>

Lorem ipsum..<br>
<div style="display: block;" id="divaa">
    Choose in the first dropdown first
</div>

<div style="display: none;" id="diva">
    <select name="produkt" id="field1">
        <option value="11">AA</option>
        <option value="12">AB</option>
        <option value="12">AC</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div style="display: none;" id="divb">
    <select name="produkt" id="field2">
        <option value="31">BA</option>
        <option value="32">BB</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div style="display: none;" id="divc">
    <select name="produkt" id="field3">
        <option value="21">CA</option>
        <option value="22">CB</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

I want to get the value from one of the choosen dropdowns to the next page, using POST.

But the result is i allways get value 21, the CA field.

What can the problem be?

Comment: option returns value which is selected if you use value="CA" then it will give you CA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, [that happends when you dont disabled a field and the value its submitted to the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7357256/disabled-form-inputs-do-not-appear-in-request).

So in other to archive that you have to, instead of just `display=none`, also disable the fields.

So try this:

```
function namedata(data) {
        if (data == 'AA') {
            $('#divaa').css('display', 'block');
            $('#divb').css('display', 'none').prop("disabled",true);
            $('#divc').css('display', 'none').prop("disabled",true);
            $('#diva').css('display', 'none').prop("disabled",true);

        }
        if (data == 'A') {
            $('#diva').css('display', 'block');
            $('#divb').css('display', 'none').prop("disabled",true);
            $('#divc').css('display', 'none').prop("disabled",true);
            $('#divaa').css('display', 'none').prop("disabled",true);


        }
        else if (data == 'B') {
            $('#divb').css('display', 'block');
            $('#diva').css('display', 'none').prop("disabled",true);
            $('#divc').css('display', 'none').prop("disabled",true);
            $('#divaa').css('display', 'none').prop("disabled",true);

        }
        else if (data == 'C') {
            $('#divc').css('display', 'block');
            $('#diva').css('display', 'none').prop("disabled",true);
            $('#divb').css('display', 'none').prop("disabled",true);
            $('#divaa').css('display', 'none').prop("disabled",true);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not only hide the divs with `display: none`, but also disable the selects inside those divs that are not active. That will prevent their values from being sent:

```
<script>
function namedata(data) {
    if (data == 'AA') {
        $('#divaa').css('display', 'block');
        $('#divb').css('display', 'none').find("select").prop("disabled", "disabled");
        $('#divc').css('display', 'none').find("select").prop("disabled", "disabled");
        $('#diva').css('display', 'none').find("select").prop("disabled", "disabled");


    }
    if (data == 'A') {
        $('#diva').css('display', 'block').find("select").prop("disabled", false);
        $('#divb').css('display', 'none').find("select").prop("disabled", "disabled");
        $('#divc').css('display', 'none').find("select").prop("disabled", "disabled");
        $('#divaa').css('display', 'none');


    }
    else if (data == 'B') {
        $('#divb').css('display', 'block').find("select").prop("disabled", false);
        $('#diva').css('display', 'none').find("select").prop("disabled", "disabled");
        $('#divc').css('display', 'none').find("select").prop("disabled", "disabled");
        $('#divaa').css('display', 'none');

    }
    else if (data == 'C') {
        $('#divc').css('display', 'block').find("select").prop("disabled", false);
        $('#diva').css('display', 'none').find("select").prop("disabled", "disabled");
        $('#divb').css('display', 'none').find("select").prop("disabled", "disabled");
        $('#divaa').css('display', 'none');

    }
}
</script>
```

You can see a demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/srnzb3cy/ (check the console to see the values that would be sent)

Answer (score 1):

Please use the power of jquerys selectors.

You do not need all these lines of code.

Try this:

```
$('#diva, #divb, #divc, #divaa').not('#div' + data.toLowerCase()).css('display', 'none').prop("disabled",true);
$('#div' + data.toLowerCase()).css('display', 'block').prop("disabled",false);
```

The first line will select all divs and deselect the one that has to be shown.
The second line will only select to div that is to be shown

Comment: This solution is neat. Just one comment: use `find("select")` to disable the dropdown, right now you are applying the `prop("disabled",true)` to the `div` instead of the `select`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want an answer using the resources you gave, but if isn't this the case, I can recommend you to use Chained selects plugin (jQuery)

It will help you a lot !

I can show you an example, try this:

```
<select name="name" id="father">
    <option value="AA">PLEASE CHOOSE</option>
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
</select>

So much easier :)<br>
<div style="display: block;" id="divaa">
    Choose in the first dropdown first
</div>

<div style="display: none;" id="divaa">
    <select name="produkt" id="field1">
        <option value="11" class="A">AA</option>
        <option value="12" class="A">AB</option>
        <option value="12" class="A">AC</option>
        <option value="31" class="B">BA</option>
        <option value="32" class="B">BB</option>
        <option value="21" class="C">CA</option>
        <option value="22" class="C">CB</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

And the only js you need is:

```
$("#field1").chained("#father");
```

You may need this:

https://github.com/tuupola/jquery_chained/blob/master/jquery.chained.min.js

Good luck !

Here's the link of the project for more info:

http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/chained