# Request.Form is null on making button as disabled

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have two buttons on my screen i am handling with one  method :
Request.Form["Approve"] becomes null as i have disabled the button, how i can get the value of Request.Form["Approve"] after disabling the button.

```
 @if(ViewBag.RequestAlreadyProcessed)
 { 
     <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn_box" value="Approve" name="Approve" disabled="disabled" />
     <input type="submit" class="btn btn_secondary btn_box" value="Reject" name="Reject" disabled="disabled"/>
 }
 else
 {
     <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn_box" value="Approve" name="Approve" />
     <input type="submit" class="btn btn_secondary btn_box" value="Reject" name="Reject" />
 }

Controller:
public async Task<ActionResult> Approve(UserApprovalModel UserApprovalModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (Request.Form["Approve"] != null)
        {
            userReg.StatusCd = "APP";
        }
        else
        {
            userReg.StatusCd = "REJ";
        }
   }
   if(userReg.StatusCd == "APP")
   {
       userReg.StatusComment = "Approved";
   }
   else if(userReg.StatusCd == "REJ")
   {
      userReg.StatusComment = "Rejected";
   }
}
```

Comment: Sadly you approach is fundamentally wrong. You should have two different controller endpoint for approval and rejection. Then bind those buttons to some client side click events which can handle the submission of form. Your controller code is doing way too much.

Comment: What is the point of 2 disabled buttons? You may as well just not include them. And as @qamar as indicated, you should have 2 different methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browser do not submit disabled control as they are read only.
there is a workaround for your problem, you make the field `readonly="readonly"` instead of `disabled="disabled"`? A readonly field value will be submitted to the server while still being non-editable by the user. A SELECT tag is an exception though.

Also as a side note,

> Disabled controls do not receive focus.
>    Disabled controls are skipped
>   in tabbing navigation.
>    Disabled controls cannot be successfully
>   posted.

(Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7357314/1709587.)

Comment: why you need a disabled button in controller?  its work can easily be done with hidden.

Comment: you can use hidden to store values for you and make your checks in controller action based on hidden.

Comment: <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn_box" value="Approve" name="Approve"  style="display:none"...this does not work either

Comment: use `<input type="hidden">` instead of buttons