# I have added some simple JS to my form and now it sends to my domain/mailer.php instead of my 'success' page

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

In order to prevent users from creating multiple submissions, I have implemented JavaScript to disable the submit button after it has been pressed.

My form page is processed by mailer.php, and then directed to a success page. Now, however, my form submits and is directed to mailer.php, and it appears the data is not submit.

I assume it has something to do with the `onsubmit` overriding the `action=mailer.php`.

Is this the cause and how can I fix it?

```
<form 
    onsubmit="document.getElementById('submit').disabled=true;document.getElementById('submit').value='Submitting, please wait...';"
    action="mailer.php" 
    method="post">
  <input 
      name="firstname" 
      type="text"
      placeholder="First Name" 
      class="form-content"/>
  </br>
  <input 
      name="surname" 
      type="text" 
      placeholder="Surname" 
      class="form-content"/>
  </br>

  [edit: removed irrelevant inputs]

  <div id="submitbutton">
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I'm confused, Your form action is set to mailer.php. Can't you just replace this with your success(.php?) page?

Comment: The mailer collects the data and then emails it to me as well as pushes into a database. The mailer then redirects to the success page/

Comment: Maybe the submit-button isn't sent through post after disabling - if you check at mailer.php --> if (isset($_POST['submit'])) ... wont work.

Comment: Any idea why it won't work? My mailer: "if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7357256/disabled-form-inputs-do-not-appear-in-the-request

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks fine.

I've duplicated your form at:

http://jsfiddle.net/p9nc27qq/

Entering the values for the form:

[image]

The action is set up to send to `http://requestb.in/1llii7k1`

This site is a debugging of HTTP requests site...

If you inspect the page you can see it's receiving correctly:

http://requestb.in/1llii7k1?inspect

[image]

http://requestb.in/1llii7k1?inspect#1ipe11

Whatever you are doing is correct, so you are proabbaly misunderstanding the problem or not handling the request correctly on your server.. but the form is perfectly fine... as evidenced above.

---

Disabled values aren't submitted with the form also. So don't check for the presence of "submit"

[Disabled form inputs do not appear in the request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7357256/disabled-form-inputs-do-not-appear-in-the-request)