# How to POST html values that are disabled ?

Tags: php

I have a disabled input field `<input type = "text" name = "text1" id = "myTExt1" value = "myData" "disabled >`, how to post the value of this input field.

Many thanks !!!

Comment: Remove the disabled tag

Comment: it wont work in the form

Comment: Instead of `disabled` you can use `readonly` which will post data.

Comment: You can get more info from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7357256/disabled-form-inputs-do-not-appear-in-the-request

Comment: @Mr.Shrestha It is clearly duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

i think you are looking for this , readonly will post data from form

```
<input type = "text" name = "text1" id = "myTExt1" value = "myData" readonly >
```