# Remove 'disabled' property from Form and re-enable

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a form with some inputs and some of those inputs are disabled. Because they are disabled, they won't submit the data that is contained in them. So I use the following jQuery code to remove the `disabled` property on submit.

```
jQuery(function ($) {        
    $('form').bind('submit', function () {
        $(this).find(':input').prop('disabled', false);
    });
});
```

When user clicks the submit button, the `disabled` property is removed, the data in those fields are sent, and a file is downloaded (I use headers so user is on same page). However, because the `disabled` property is now removed, the user can modify those fields and resubmit the form with their own data, which I do not want.

My question is, how can I modify my code to re-disable those certain fields once the form is submitted.

Comment: Is the data in those fields important for the user to see? If not, you could use inputs with `type="hidden"`. Otherwise, just set the `disabled` property back to true after submitting (you can use a class to keep track of which inputs are supposed to be disabled).

Comment: Yeah it is important for user to see but I do not want them to edit it.

Comment: How would I re-disable the fields after submission?

Comment: When the submit button is pushed, the browser will not post-back and serve HTML again. Only thing that happens is that a file is downloaded which is the behavior I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for `readonly` rather than `disabled` (and without jQuery):

```
<input type="text" name="readOnlyValue" value="666" readonly="readonly" />
```

This topic has been asked differently and [answered in details here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7357256/disabled-form-inputs-do-not-appear-in-the-request#answer-7357314). In short:

- `disabled` prevents focus and prevents from sending the data
- `readonly` allows the focus but prevents modifying and lets the data be sent

Be careful though as the user is easily able to change the `input`'s value by hacking the page. So you should be ready to handle malicious users on the server side.

Comment: Yeah I actually ended up doing this just before you submitted your answer. See my answer above yours because I wanted it to be styled like a disabled button

Comment: Saw that, I was a little upset to see your answer right after I posted mine haha! By the way I encourage you to add some style anyway to "not-normal" (even disabled) inputs as the default browser style can change a lot across browsers.

Comment: I'll give you the answer credit since you posted right before I did and I am pretty sure your (now-removed) comment was the reason I was on this track

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround.

Instead of setting each input as `disabled`, I set them as `readonly` but to make it have the same styling as a `disabled` field, I added the following CSS

```
input:read-only {
    background-color: #EBEBE4;
    color: #545454;
    border-style: hidden;
    padding: 3px;
}
```

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b20bm53r/)** to show a sample of the difference between the two

Answer (score 0):

To directly answer your question: You could re-disable your buttons in a callback-function if you submit your form with an asynchronous xmlhttprequest.

However, I think the easiest solution is to add the data yet another time as type="hidden" like this:

```
<input type="text" value="samedata" disabled>
<input type="hidden" name="actualnamedfield" value="samedata">
```

Only the first one is visible and only the second one gets submitted.

Comment: Right but then I would have 2 fields for every input that is disabled. I just ended up making the field read-only so I don't have to deal with any jQuery/Javascript

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I am suggesting. It requires minimal work, is not conflicting, gives the native disabled-look on any platform and requires no JS.