# hibernate get id=0 Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp, ssl

I have error for edit with hibernate + spring. I already search in this. But still can't find solution. I write C R U D code, all work fine like add/delete, but I get errors when I edit/update the database.

Kindly can you help me to find a solution? 
Thanks.

Here's my code:

modal/entity EmployeStatus.java

```
@Entity
@Table
public class EmployeeStatus {

    @Id
    @Column
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    public EmployeeStatus() {
    }

    public EmployeeStatus(int id, String name) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "EmployeeStatus [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + "]";
    }

}
```

Dao impl EmployeeStatusDaoImpl.java

```
@Repository
public class EmployeeStatusDaoImpl implements EmployeeStatusDao {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EmployeeStatusDaoImpl.class);

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public EmployeeStatus findById(int id) {

    return (EmployeeStatus)sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(EmployeeStatus.class, id);
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<EmployeeStatus> findAll() {
    Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    List<EmployeeStatus> employeeList = session.createQuery("from EmployeeStatus").list();
    return employeeList;
}


public void save(EmployeeStatus es) {
    //sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(es);
    Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    session.persist(es);
}


public void update(EmployeeStatus es) {
    //Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    //session.update(es);
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().update(es);
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().flush();
    //sessions.getCurrentSession().update(es);
    logger.info("Employee Status updated successfully, Employee Status Details="+es);
}


public void delete(int id) {
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(findById(id));

}


}
```

service impl EmployeeStatusServiceImpl.java

```
@Service
public class EmployeeStatusServiceImpl implements EmployeeStatusService{

@Autowired
private EmployeeStatusDao employeeStatusDao;

@Transactional
public EmployeeStatus findById(int id) {
    return employeeStatusDao.findById(id);
}

@Transactional
public List<EmployeeStatus> findAll() {
    return employeeStatusDao.findAll();
}

@Transactional
public void save(EmployeeStatus es) {
    employeeStatusDao.save(es);

}

@Transactional
public void update(EmployeeStatus es) {
    employeeStatusDao.update(es);

}

@Transactional
public void delete(int id) {
    employeeStatusDao.delete(id);

}


}
```

controller EmployeeStatusController.java

```
@Controller
public class EmployeeStatusController {

@Autowired
private EmployeeStatusService employeeStatusService;

@RequestMapping(value="employeeStatus", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String list(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("empStat", new EmployeeStatus());
    model.addAttribute("list", this.employeeStatusService.findAll());
    return "empStat";
}



    //For add 
    @RequestMapping(value= "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addEmployeeStatus(@ModelAttribute("empStat") EmployeeStatus es){
        //new employee status, call save
        this.employeeStatusService.save(es);
        return "redirect:/employeeStatus";

    }

    //for edit
    @RequestMapping(value= "/update", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String updateEmployeeStatus(@ModelAttribute("empStat") EmployeeStatus es){

        //existing Employee status, call update function from service

        employeeStatusService.update(es);
        return "redirect:/employeeStatus";

    }

    @RequestMapping("/remove/{id}")
    public String removeEmployeeStatus(@PathVariable("id") int id){

        this.employeeStatusService.delete(id);
        return "redirect:/employeeStatus";
    }

    //for call edit in list
        @RequestMapping("/edit/{id}")
        public String editEmployeeStatus(@PathVariable("id") int id, Model model){

            model.addAttribute("list",   this.employeeStatusService.findAll());
            model.addAttribute("empStat", this.employeeStatusService.findById(id));
        return "empStat";
    }


}
```

jsp employeeStatus.jsp

```
   ` <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles"%>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>


    <div id="page-wrapper">
    <div class="container-fluid">

        <!-- Page Heading -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h1 class="page-header">Data Master</h1>
                <ol class="breadcrumb">
                    <li><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> <a href="/">Dashboard</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="active"><i class="fa fa-table"></i> Employee Status List</li>
                </ol>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->
        <div class="page-content">
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <div class="panel panel-green">
                    <div class="panel-heading">Employee Status</div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>ID</th>
                                    <th>Name</th>
                                    <th>Operation</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <c:forEach items="${list}" var="empStatlist">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><a><c:out value="${empStatlist.id}" /></a></td>
                                        <td><a><c:out value="${empStatlist.name}" /></a></td>
                                        <td align="center">
                                            <a href="<c:url value='/edit/${empStatlist.id}' />">
                                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
                                            </a> 
                                                    
                                            <a href="<c:url value='/remove/${empStatlist.id}' />">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
                                            </a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </c:forEach>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <br>
                <div class="panel panel-success">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h3 class="panel-title">Add Employee Status</h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <c:url var="addAction" value="/add"></c:url>

                                <form:form action="${addAction}" commandName="empStat">
                                    <table>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><form:label path="name">
                                                    <spring:message text="Name" />
                                                </form:label>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <form:input path="name" />
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td colspan="2">
                                                <input type="submit" value="<spring:message text="Add"/>" />
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </form:form>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <br>
                        <div class="panel panel-success">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h3 class="panel-title">Edit Employee Status</h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <c:url var="editAction" value="/update"></c:url>

                                <form:form action="${editAction}" commandName="empStat">
                                    <table>

                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    <form:label path="id" >
                                                        <spring:message text="ID" />
                                                    </form:label>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <!-- <form:input path="id" />  -->
                                                    <form:input path="id" readonly="true" size="8"   disabled="true" />
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>

                                        <tr>
                                            <td><form:label path="name">
                                                    <spring:message text="Name" />
                                                </form:label>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <form:input path="name" />
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td colspan="2">
                                                    <input type="submit" value="<spring:message text="Update"/>" />
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </form:form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
            </div>
        </div>                
    </div>
    </div>
```

when i hit simbol edit button, i get the data, like id and name
[get id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aprrK.png)

but when i hit edit button i got this error

```
15:48:18,574 DEBUG AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource:108 - Adding     transactional method 'EmployeeStatusServiceImpl.update' with attribute:     PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; ''
Sat May 14 15:48:18 WIB 2016 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without     server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL     5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be     established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with     existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property     is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting     useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server    certificate verification.
15:48:18,587  INFO EmployeeStatusDaoImpl:50 - Employee Status updated successfully, Employee Status Details=EmployeeStatus [id=0, name=Semi Permanent]
Hibernate: 
    update
        EmployeeStatus 
    set
        name=? 
    where
        id=?
15:48:18,603 ERROR AbstractBatcher:73 - Exception executing batch: 
org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row</code>
```

The id=0 why?

How I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the HTML generated by your jsp includes **disabled**  on the id input, your answer is

> Elements with Disabled attribute are not submitted or you can say
>   their values are not posted.

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7357256/disabled-form-inputs-do-not-appear-in-the-request)

Comment: oh my bad. thanks for your solution sir. so i just need to change disabled attribute to readonly. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Please do following things in EmployeeStatus.java

1. Change `private int id`; to `private Long Id`
2. Remove the setter method for this id property .