# Disable bootstrap switch after onswitchchange

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-switch

I am new at coding with bootstrap and jquery. how can i disable bootstrap switch in "onswitchchange" method option

Here my javascript/jquery code:

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").bootstrapSwitch({
    size:"mini",
    onSwitchChange:function(event, state) {
      this.disabled = true; //checkbox change into disabled
    }
  });
```

i also tried to change `this.disabled = true` into `$(this).setDisabled(true);` and it returning error of course. i just want to know how to call `setDisable` method inside `onswitchchange` method. if it cannot be like that. is there any other way to disable the switch after change/click it it?

Comment: Use the `attr()` function in jQuery to achieve this. I've posted an answer below. Note that `disabled` elements aren't posted with a form - if you want their values to be posted, use `readonly` instead :)

Comment: @GeoffJames i tried it before. didnt work either. it just disabled the hidden check box. but not full element. i still can click and change the state.

Comment: Can you post your code that contains the switch and checkbox, please? You *could* use the `.closest('element')` selector to find the container that the `checkbox` is in, and then disable that. Bit hard to say exactly without seeing surrounding HTML - if you post the code, I'll update my answer :)

Comment: I've edited my answer to include how to use the `.closest()` function, which will hopefully help a little. I can't be entirely sure/accurate as to what your selector needs to be, but if you wouldn't mind updating your OP with the surrounding HTML for your Bootstrap switch, then I can add to my answer and be a little more specific :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE:** When using the Bootstrap Switch, you can use one of 2 functions:

```
$(this).bootstrapSwitch("toggleDisabled"); // toggles whether `this` is disabled

$(this).bootstrapSwitch("disabled",true); // just disables the `this` element
```

So in your `onSwitchChange` handler, you can use the `bootstrapSwitch("disabled", true)` method:

```
onSwitchChange:function(event, state) {
  $(this).bootstrapSwitch('disabled', true);
}
```

There's no real point in "toggling", as it's in a handler for when it changes - when it's disabled, it shouldn't change again.

---

**Previous answer - for those wanting to use jQuery to disable elements**

If you want to set a form element to `disabled`, you need to declare its `disabled` *attribute*.

There is controversy whether this should be set to `true`, just declared, or set to `disabled`.

Personally (and the most favourable/compatible) is to set `disabled=disabled`.

---

To set element attributes using jQuery, you can use the `attr()` function *(first argument is attribute, second argument is value)*:

```
onSwitchChange:function(event, state) {
  $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled'); // set the element's disabled attribute
}
```

**NOTE:** Since you are disabling the checkbox - this means the value of it won't get posted with a `form`.

---

*If* you need the value to be POSTed with a form, use the `readonly` attribute and set it to `readonly`:

```
onSwitchChange:function(event, state) {
  $(this).attr('readonly', 'readonly'); //checkbox is readonly, but still POSTed 
}
```

---

Here's a great answer explaining the differences between `disabled` and `readonly`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7357314/6240567

---

**EDIT**: The above code only disables/readonly the `checkbox` itself. In order to disable the container, or other elements within that you will need to use the `.closest()` selector.

Top tip on selectors, and which ones you need:

- `div` matches on element *type* - in this case it selects `div` elements.
- `.some-class` matches on class - in this case any element that has "`some-class`" as the class
- `#someId` matches on element's `id` - in this case it selects the element with the `id` of "`someId`"

With that said, you can then select the `closest` element that you're looking to disable (or the container for it)

For example:

```
  // set the checkbox's closest element with "bootstrapSwitch" class, to disabled
  $(this).closest('.bootstrapSwitch').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: thank you for helping.. ive found the solution. it need to be replace with `$(this).bootstrapSwitch("toggleDisabled");` or `$(this).bootstrapSwitch("disabled",true);`. it will be great if you edit your answer as this. so i can accept it as the best answer. and it will help the others who have the same problem as me.

Comment: Thanks @Fadhil, I've included this at the top of my answer :) Glad you got it working

Comment: ok thank you...fyi: im working with ajax right now. it will send the switch state to the database. so i need to disable the switch until ajax get the callback. after that the switch will be enabled.:)

Comment: Awesome stuff! Happy coding! :)

Comment: `$(this).bootstrapSwitch('readonly', true);` works for me. I replaced the second parameter from 'readonly' to `true`