# disabled not submitting in php

Tags: javascript, php

I have a select box in my form and inside that select box there's a list of a,b,c and others.and I have a input type="text" which is disabled.now, when I select others in select box the input will be enabled so that the user can type anything that cannot be found in the select item.this function works fine but, the only problem is that when I try it now to update its not submitting..can anyone help me..

**html**

```
<Select name="category" id="category" class="form-control" onChange="category();">
    <option value="<?php echo $a; ?>" selected="selected">Please Select a Category</option>
    <option value="a">A</option>
    <option value="b">B</option>
    <option value="c">C</option>
    <option value="OTHERS">Other/s</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="Others" name="Others" value="<?php echo $Others; ?>" class="form-control" placeholder="Other/s" disabled="true">
```

**javascript**

```
$(function(){
    $("#category").change(function(){
        if($(this).val()=="OTHERS"){
            console.log(true);
            $("#Others").removeAttr("disabled");
        }
        else{
            console.log(false);
            $("#Others").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        }
    });
});
```

**php**

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $ID = $_GET['ID'];
    $Category = $_POST['Category'];
    $Others = $_POST['Others'];

    if($LTS->update($ID,$Category,$Others)){
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Successfully Updated!');</script>";
    }
    else {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Updating Failed!');</script>";
    }
}

if(isset($_GET['ID'])) {
    $ID = $_GET['ID'];
    extract($LTS->getID($ID)); 
}
?>
```

**class.user.php**

```
public function update($ID,$Category,$Others) {
    try{
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE sfund SET Category = :Categoryy,Others = :Others WHERE ID = :ID");
        $stmt->bindparam(":Category", $Category);
        $stmt->bindparam(":Others", $Others);

        $stmt->bindparam(":ID", $ID);
        $stmt->execute();
        return true;
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: $(#Others") needs a quote after the first parenthesis

Comment: oh, i'm sorry its just a typo..i updated my question

Comment: what do you mean by not submitting? is it ajax?

Comment: `$("category")`, you're forgetting something here.. Should be `$("#category")` (missing `#`)

Comment: You need to add a **#** in front of category on the selector

Comment: the disabled form input not submitting data. but when i tried to remove the disabled="true" in my input it successfully updated but with disabled is true the updating is failed

Comment: its a typo again.sorry for that

Comment: If the inputs are disabled, they won't be submitted, as they are *disabled*. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7357256/disabled-form-inputs-do-not-appear-in-the-request so that's working as intended. So with your code, if the function is working, the input won't be active unless you select `OTHERS`

Comment: @Qirel yeah thats right so, what should i do to fix it?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you want to achieve, so I'm not sure what you want to "fix". That being said, if you want the input to be submitted regardless, but only editable if the select is set to `OTHERS`, just make it `readonly` instead of `disabled`.

Comment: @Qirel i already saw link you posted but if change the disable to readonly the user can't change it right?

Comment: why not instead of removing and adding the attribute `disabled`, try making it `true` or `false` like `$("#Others").prop("disabled",true);` and `$("#Others").prop("disabled",false);`

Comment: @MarkVincentManjac i'll your code..wait..

Comment: @MarkVincentManjac tried your code but its not working..i think there's something wrong with my code..can you please help me edit the above code..

Comment: so the input and select tags from above is inside the form tag?

Comment: @MarkVincentManjac yeah

Comment: what is your code in submitting the form?

Comment: wait i'll edit my code

Comment: i'll already updated my above code

Comment: If the field is not supposed to be modified by the user than you should be careful when using it on the server-side. Anyone can make a request to your server and fake the values to be whatever they like. Or they can just use the developer console to change values.

Comment: @MarkVincentManjac if my code doesn't work on you maybe you could just make your own sample..

Comment: why not make a short hand ajax request to pass the value from your form to the php.

Comment: @Terminus lets say a user select "OTHERS" because the user did not find the item he's looking for of course he will select OTHERS and a input text will be enabled so that the user can input what he want to input there.

Comment: @MarkVincentManjac how can i do that..i'm sorry for my question, i'm just a newbie in javascript

Comment: I've posted my own solution. Just ask me if you have questions in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
$('#submitButton').click(function() {
  var others = $('#Others').val();
  var category = $('#category').val();
  $.post('script.php', {
    action: 'submit',
    others: others,
    cat: category
  });
});
```

`script.php` is the name of your php file. include the path if it is inside the folder. 
In your PHP, change `$_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"` with 
`isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == "submit"` to separate it from other ajax that you will create.

Comment: where isthis that you said on a comment above $("#Others").prop("disabled",true); and $("#Others").prop("disabled",false); –

Comment: you just change your code `$("#Others").removeAttr("disabled");` to `$("#Others").prop("disabled",false);` and `$("#Others").attr("disabled", "disabled");` to `$("#Others").prop("disabled",true);`

Comment: do i need to remove the disabled="true" in my input?

Comment: try to set `disabled="false"` and check if it is ok.

Comment: i already tried it but its not working..maybe i just need to set a hidden field?

Comment: If you'll gonna use ajax. It will work perfectly with or without the form tag.

Comment: yeah..i have this html code <input type="text" id="input">
<button onclick="copyText()">Go</button><br>
<input type="text" id="output"> and javascript function copyText(){
   document.getElementById("output").value=document.getElementById("input").value;
}

Comment: but i want it to be automatic without pressing the button..how can i do that?

Comment: what do you mean by automatically without pressing the button? you mean when the user type inside the input text?

Comment: yeah..when a user type the first input it will automatically copy to the second textbox without hitting any button. like the one in my comment it used ".click"

Comment: then the jQuery of that is `$('#input1').keydown(function(){
$('#input2').val(this.value);});`