# Showing disabled appearance to checkbox without using disabled attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

I have to show checkbox in disabled format using css. Don't want to use disabled attribute due to some technical reason. If i used disabled attribute it is not passing on checkbox value to next page.Hence i don't want to use disabled attribute.
can someone tell me how to show checkbox in disabled format using css ?

[image]

Comment: But...what if the user clicks it? It'll deselect it.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/pointer-events/

Comment: I suppose making it readonly is a better alternative.

Comment: @nnnnnn :- on click i am returning false;

Comment: If you know what the value is already, and you just want to display it to the user, simply send the value manually using a `<input type="hidden" name="someName" value="true"/>` This way you will send the state of that element to the next page, and use disable to show the checkbox properly.

Comment: @Narxx. It is in my mind . but there are 60 to 65 checkboxes present on page. Hence i want to try that last option.  When user click on on disable page.i am disabling all checkboxes. And on click of submit form, i am enabling all checkboxes, so that they can pass on value to next form.

Comment: How about trying out @Spidi'sWeb idea, changing the disabled into readonly? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7357256/disabled-form-inputs-do-not-appear-in-the-request