# Check box value is coming as false if it is disabled in primefaces

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2

I have a requirement like this.

there is a file uploader alopng with checkbox and save, cancel buttons.

I have to disable the check box if the file is invalid and the selection should stay.

After disabling if I click the save button the checkbox value is coming as false in backing bean eventhough it's showing as checked in the dialog.

While debugging I seen that the primeface framework is not getting the id of the disabled checkbox,

Here is my xhtml file:

```
    <h:form id="fileupload_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <h:panelGroup id="fileupload_Panel">
    <p:message for="fileupload_Panel"></p:message>

    <p:panelGrid styleClass="noBorderGrid global_docs" columns="4">

        <h:outputText style="min-width:100px!important; margin-left: 42px;"></h:outputText>
        <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="tt" value="#{bean.selectedDocs}"/>
        <h:outputText value="xx}"/>


        <h:outputText style="min-width:100px!important; margin-left: 42px;" rendered="#{cc.attrs.bean != null and cc.attrs.bean.currentDocument != null}"></h:outputText>
        <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="checkBox" value="#{fileBean.tqpReport}"  disabled="${not fileBean.isActive}"/>
        <h:outputText value="xxxx"/>
        <p:tooltip for="t" value="xxxx"/>

    </p:panelGrid>

    <p:fileUpload id="documentFileUploader" fileUploadListener="#{bean.uploadDocumentsListener}" 
                    mode="advanced" dragDropSupport="true" multiple="true" auto="true"  update="@form" process="@form"
                    onstart="PF('ajax').show();"  onerror="PF('ajax').hide();"
                    style="width: 98%; max-width: 480px; max-height: 150px; overflow: auto;" styleClass="file-uploader-drag-drop" label="#{msgs.choose}" />
    </h:panelGroup>


     <p:panelGrid styleClass="noBorderGrid buttonTable" columns="3" style="float:right;">
         <p:commandButton id="save" icon="ui-icon-disk" styleClass="blue_button" value="${msgs.save}" style="float:right;"
        process="@form" update="@form" action="#{bean.save()}"/>
         <p:commandButton id="cancel" icon="ui-icon-close" styleClass="blue_button" value="${msgs.cancel}"
        action="#{bean.cancel()}"  style="float:right;"
        process="@this"/>
</p:panelGrid> 

 </h:form>
```

While debugging I found that in the

```
   public void decode(FacesContext context, UIComponent component)
```

method of

```
   SelectBooleanCheckboxRenderer.java class
```

the id of the disabled check box is null from that statement. I don't understand why? If the check box is not disabled I am getting the correct value.

```
  String submittedValue = (String) context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get(clientId + "_input");
```

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, your checkbox is in disabled state and value is coming as false as disabled fields are not submitted on submit button and default value is false.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I tried with hidden variable trick, it's working for me

hidden variable in xhtm file, and getters and setter in backing bean.

```
<h:inputHidden id="checkBoxSelection" value="#{fileBean.checkBoxSelection}"/>
```

While saving, I am getting the selection,and setting to the hidden variable like,

```
 <p:commandButton id="save" icon="ui-icon-disk" styleClass="blue_button" value="${msgs.save}" style="float:right;"
    process="@form" update="@form" action="#{fileBean.saveUploadedDocuments(cc.attrs.id)}" 
 onclick="sendCheckBoxSelection('fileupload_form_widget_tqpReportCheckBox','fileupload_form:checkBoxSelection');"/>
```

and the js function is:

```
function sendCheckBoxSelection(checkBoxId,hiddenparamId){
var checkBoxSelection = false;
var tqpCheckBox = getWidgetVarById(checkBoxId);
if (tqpCheckBox != null){
    checkBoxSelection = PrimeFaces.widgets[checkBoxId].input.is(':checked')
    document.getElementById(hiddenparamId).value = checkBoxSelection;
  }
}

 function getWidgetVarById(id) {
for (var propertyName in PrimeFaces.widgets) {
  if (propertyName === id) {
    return PrimeFaces.widgets[propertyName];
   }
  }
}
```

So, the checkbox value will set to the backing bean  while saving .

[http://blog.hatemalimam.com/intro-to-primefaces-widgetvar](http://blog.hatemalimam.com/intro-to-primefaces-widgetvar/)

Answer (score 0):

Disabled elements are not posted as part form submission; you can see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7357314/2780051) for some more details. Assuming that you're using a ViewScoped bean you can use AJAX to post the value back to the bean when the value changes.