# cannot INSERT getElementbyID value into SQL Table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql

Dear Stackoverflow members,this question might seem very trivial and honestly I search for an answer however although there are similar queries around, none of the solutions delivered seem to work on what I am trying to achieve. I will put forth a generic snippet to understand what I am trying to achieve.

```
var dd = addday.getDate() + xdays; //addition of days to user input date 

document.getElementById("Days").value= displaydate;//loading date to Days
```

where displaydate is in the following format:

```
var displaydate = dd+'/' + mm + '/' + y; //showing date format
```

and value shown in real time is displayed in the following input (disabled) box:

```
<label><b>Expiry Date:</b></label><input type="text" name="Days2" id ="Days2" disabled>
```

All the above is in a form. What I want to achieve thereafter is that when the user presses submit, that value attained and displayed by the getElementById is inserted in a table.

```
$addquery2="INSERT INTO 3pxdef_tb(defRef,tlpID,RaisedBy,RaisedDate,defDesc,defCAT,expDate,closedBy,closedDate,acID)VALUES('$_POST[def]','$_POST[tlptsel]','$_POST[raisedby]','$_POST[draised]','$_POST[des]','$_POST[catsel]','$_POST[Days]','$_POST[clby]','$_POST[closeddate]','$acindex')";
```

Unfortunately this is not working since an undefined index is being returned by the system.

Can I ask your assistance in this matter?

Thanking you so much.

Comment: disabled property input field  should  not post  the value to next page. you can remove disabled property  and try again

Comment: in your SQL query replace '$_POST[Days]' with '$_POST[Days2]' i think your problem is just a typo

Answer (score 1):

There are two errors or I should say mistakes in your code first
**Disabled input tags cannot be posted**

see this for more information
[Disabled form inputs do not appear in the request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7357256/disabled-form-inputs-do-not-appear-in-the-request)

Second
Just like what [Luigi D'Amico](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4141943/luigi-damico) said

You're Calling "Days" as id in your JS code but in your html code you have "Days2" as an ID and Name. Rename your Days2 into Days. Your php script also uses that one.

Answer (score 0):

You say:

```
document.getElementById("Days").value
```

But the html tags id is **"Days2"**

```
<input type="text" name="Days2" id ="Days2"
```

Let us know if this was the issue or if it was just a typo

Comment: Dear Team Members, the input tag error was known. The issue was I copy and pasted the code and changed the variables at the last minute. However the good news the non posting was all related to a disabled input tag. Thank you guys !!! very much appreciated.

Comment: happy you sorted :)