# Post modal form values to a PHP file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form in a modal. When I press the submit button the php file runs with the following errors:
Notice: Undefined index: phone1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\site\bank.php on line 2
Notice: Undefined index: charge1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\site\bank.php on line 4

Here is the PHP code in bank.php:

```html
<?php
echo  $_POST["phone"];
echo "</br>";
echo  $_POST["charge"];
?>
```

Here is the modal contents:

```html
<!-- Modal content-->

<div class="modal fade" id="register" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title here</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form id="modal-form" class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="bank.php">
          <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-xs-6" style="float:right;">
                <label>phone numer:</label>
                <input id="phone" type="text" class="form-control" name="phone" value="pre filled value" disabled/>
                <span id='display'></span>
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-6" style="float:left;">
                <label>charge:</label>
                <input style="font-size:17px; font-weight:bold;" id="charge" type="text" class="form-control" name="charge" value="some other prefilled value" disabled/>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
              <button class="btn btn-danger btn-default pull-right" data- dismiss="modal" style="margin-left:10px;">close</button>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"> submit </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        modal footer
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

I would be thankful if some one help me figure out what;s wrong with this

Comment: Your form has `phone1` and your echo is `$_POST["phone"]` which one is correct ?

Comment: well the name is phone1 not phone.... and charge1 not charge.... names are sent, not ids....

Comment: You are naming your parameters with numbers (phone1, charge1) but your php code echoes them without numbers (`$_POST['change']`)

Comment: Forms post the name attribute, not the id. So whatever you put in the name attribute is what shows up on the PHP side.

Comment: forms don't natively send in disabled parameters. Possible answer to your issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7357314/6622781)

Comment: Also, try var_dump($_POST); to see which fields you are getting.

Comment: Sorry I edited this issue but its not the point , I just forgot to change them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not relevant anymore, OP edited his question. **see edit for relevant answer**!

the name of the post variable is defined by the `name`attribute of the input, not the id.
therefore in your bank.php you will have `$_POST['phone1']` and `$_POST['charge1']`available.
you can always just `var_dump($_POST);` to see all available post variables.

**Edit**: Also, disabled inputs are not being sent on submit. You can work around that fact by just adding a second hidden input for each disabled one like that:

```
<!-- Modal content-->

<div class="modal fade" id="register" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title here</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form id="modal-form" class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="bank.php">
          <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-xs-6" style="float:right;">
                <label>phone numer:</label>
                <input id="phoneDisabled" type="text" class="form-control" name="phoneDisabled" value="pre filled value" disabled/>
                <input id="phone" type="hidden" class="form-control" name="phone" value="pre filled value" disabled/>
                <span id='display'></span>
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-6" style="float:left;">
                <label>charge:</label>
                <input style="font-size:17px; font-weight:bold;" id="chargeDisabled" type="text" class="form-control" name="chargeDisabled" value="some other prefilled value" disabled/>
                <input style="font-size:17px; font-weight:bold;" id="charge" type="hidden" class="form-control" name="charge" value="some other prefilled value" disabled/>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
              <button class="btn btn-danger btn-default pull-right" data- dismiss="modal" style="margin-left:10px;">close</button>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"> submit </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        modal footer
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

**Edit2:** Or, just change `disabled` attribute to `readonly`

Comment: I have changed the name1 to name but still the same problem and here is the var_dump($_POST) result: array(0) { }

Comment: WOW that's great thanks , disabled fields was the point, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

The name in your `$_POST` variable and the html `input` name are both different. Please try to make them the same and hopefully, your code will work.

Change `name=phone1` to `name=phone` or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

You have set both of those inputs as **disabled**. Forms by default won't post those. You probably need to grab the vars with JavaScript, or remove the disabled attributes, again, with JavaScript.