# $_POST function is called but form variables are not passing on

Tags: php

I am trying for reset password module in a project. The resetpwd.php file gets the reset password and passing on the form variables to the updatepwd.php file for updating into database. $_POST function is called successfully when submit key is pressed but  form variables are not passed on the updatepwd.php file.

```
resetpwd.php

<form id='frdpwd' method ="post"  action="/updatepwd.php" autocomplete="off">
<label for="Name">Name :</label>
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" disabled = "disabled" size =25 value="<?php echo $name; ?>" >
<label for="email">Email ID :</label>
<input type="email" id="email" name="email" disabled = "disabled" size =25 value="<?php echo $email; ?>" >
<input type="password" id="pwd" name="pwd" size = 25 placeholder="Your password (Required).." onkeyup='check();'>
<input type="submit" name = "resetpwdsubmit" value="Submit" >
<input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>

updatepwd.php
<?php
    if(isset($_POST["resetpwdsubmit"])){
    $rname = $_POST["name"]);
    $remail = strtolower($_POST["email"]);
    $rpwd = $_POST["pwd"];
    $rcpwd = $_POST["cpwd"];

    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Check : " . $rname . "');</script>"; 

        if($rpwd==$rcpwd && $rname!="" && $remail!="" && $rpwd!=""){
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('ready to update the pwd : " . $_POST["pwd"] . "');</script>"; 
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Is this pasted exactly as it is in your file?

Comment: try var_dump($_REQUEST)

Comment: Maybe because they're `disabled`??? `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');`

Comment: disable property of course, but we are try get password, not email

Comment: To @AbraCadaver's comment.. from [input#disabled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attr-disabled): _"[...] a disabled control's value isn't submitted with the form."_

Comment: Really?  What are you trying to get here: `&& $rname!="" && $remail!=""` ?

Comment: Your form doesn't prompt for cpwd and thus the if statement is never true.

Comment: I can able to get the variable pwd, but the name and email id which was extracted from the php code and embedded on the form text boxes are not able to pick up in the POST method

Comment: @ManikandanRaghavan where is `$email` and `$name` set?

Comment: Also, disabled input fields do not get send in form POST data. https://stackoverflow.com/a/7357314/5749295

Comment: @Ice76, Thanks for your information. the variables $email and $name is extracted from the database when the form is loading. As you have clearly mentioned the disabled input field can't throw the variables in the POST method. I have used the tag such as <input type=hidden name ="name" value="values"> to resolve the issue. Again Thanks for your valuable time.

Answer (score 1):

You are not receiving the fields because [disabled form fields do not get sent with the request](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7357314/5749295)

You also have a typo:

Change

```
$rname = $_POST["name"]);
```

To

```
$rname = $_POST["name"];
```

Comment: I tried both the way : $rname = $_POST["name"]); and $rname = $_POST["name"];, its not picking up

Comment: @ManikandanRaghavan reading the other comments, there are a few problems. look through them and make the fixes

Comment: @ManikandanRaghavan when you disable an input field, it does not get sent.

Answer (score 0):

As you have clearly mentioned the disabled input field can't throw the variables in the POST method. I have used the tag such as  to resolve the issue. Thanks all for your valuable time.