# Changing input text value with jQuery in form

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I have 2 checkbox input and 1 input text.
[image]
When i click on checkbox #1 i want to disabled checkbox #2 then, add a text (my-text-1) in input text and make it unchangeable

When i click on checkbox #2 i want to disabled checkbox #1 then, add a text (my-text-2) in input text and make it unchangeable

with jQuery 3.4.1

So, it works but ...

When i submit the form, the value of the input text is not recorded in my database. It's like the field is empty.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#checkbox1").on('click', function(){
  if($(this).is(':checked')) {
   $("#inputtext").val("my-text-1").prop('disabled', true);          
   $("#checkbox2").prop('disabled', true);
  } else {
      $("#inputtext").val("").prop('disabled', false);
   $("#checkbox2").prop('disabled', false);
  }
 });
    
    $("#checkbox2").on('click', function(){
  if($(this).is(':checked')) {
      $("#inputtext").val("my-text-2").prop('disabled', true);
   $("#checkbox1").prop('disabled', true);
  } else {
      $("#inputtext").val("").prop('disabled', false);
   $("#checkbox1").prop('disabled', false);
  }
 });
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label>Checkbox #1</label>
<input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox" value="" name="checkbox1"><br/>
<label>Checkbox #2</label><input id="checkbox2" type="checkbox" value="" name="checkbox2"><br/>
<label>Text : </label><input name="inputtext" id="inputtext" type="text" size="50" maxlength="50" value="" />
```

Comment: `When i submit the form, the value of the input text is not recorded in my database`. Where is your code then?

Comment: Is this really a "php" question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `disabled` property on the `input[text]` element use `readonly` property. Data for `disabled` elements does not get submitted:

```
$("#inputtext").val("my-text-1").prop('readonly', true);
```

Another alternative would be to enable the element prior to submitting the form.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7357256/disabled-form-inputs-do-not-appear-in-the-request)

Comment: You're right @PeterKA : disabled element does not get submitted