# Why does <form:input disabled="true"/> not work when the form is submitted?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jsp

I have a simple

```
<form:hidden id="someIdHere" path="somePathHere" value="${somePathHere}" disabled="true"/>
```

The form's action points to a POST method from the controller. Everything works fine until the moment where the form's `modelAttribute` is mapped to the `MyForm` object from controller:

```
public class MyForm{
    private String somePathHere;
    private String someAnotherPathHere;
    //getters;setters;
}
```

I have one more `<form:hidden>` for the `someAnotherPathHere` attribute but without `disabled="true"`. This field is getting filled but the one where the `disabled` attribute is **true** is not getting filled.

Comment: Can you try `th:value="${somePathHere}"` instead of `value="${somePathHere}"`

Comment: yes because inputs which have `disabled` attribute doesn't gets submit to server instead use `readonly` attribute.Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7357314/10606400) answer.