# Send multiple data using checkbox via ajax

Tags: php, ajax

> I have created a form which contains a table, the purpose of this is table is to select the desired fees to manage

```
<form method="POST" action="manage_fees.php" id="manage_form">
     <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="table">
        <thead>
            <tr class="p-4">
            <th scope="col">Select</th>
            <th scope="col">School fees</th>
            <th scope="col">Amount</th>
            <th scope="col">type</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>              
            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input check_amount" name="local_fees">
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="check_amount"></label>
            </div>
            </td>
            <td name="selected_fees">Local fees</td>
            <td name="amount">200</td>
            <td>University fees</td>
            </tr>
       </tbody>
     </table>
     <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit">Create</button>
     </div>
    </form>
```

> Now I want to record it all data("fee name and total payment") that has checked in checkbox table and save in database using ajax.

> Once the fees is selected it will display on the on `input` just like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/rLu8ygs0/)

```
 <div class="form-group">
    label for="fs">Fees selected</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fs" name="fs" required disabled>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
     <label for="tp">Total payment</label>
     <input type="number" class="form-control" id="tp" name="tp" required disabled>
 </div>
```

> Now, the problem is that im having trouble saving the data that has been checked in table seems there is no data that has been pass in the input.

Sumbit.php

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$fs = $_POST['fs'];
$tp = $_POST['tp'];
$result = $connect->query("INSERT INTO manage_fees (fs,tp) VALUES ('$fs','$tp')") or die($connect->error());
}
```

> Instead of this way how will send the data using ajax?

Comment: `disabled` values doesn't get submitted to server so easy fix will be using `readonly` attribute . Also , check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7357256/disabled-form-inputs-do-not-appear-in-the-request) post

Comment: and those two inputs are not inside form tag put them inside form tag .

Comment: Thank you again for you help! Now it works perfectly my problem right now is when you check 2 checkboxes it only saves the first checkbox value how will I get the data foreach checkbox that has been checked to save it in database?

Comment: Hi, sorry for late reply check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997252/get-post-from-multiple-checkboxes) post .