# reading data from view from textbox (input)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, input, textbox, formcollection

I am using mvc asp.net trying to get data from form with FormCollection

this is my code in my view:

```
<input disabled="disabled" id="resultHome" name="resultHome"/>
```

this is the code used in my controller

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult addStatistic(StatisticModel model, FormCollection form)
    {
        string goaltimeHome = form["resultHome"];
    }
```

the value is always null. Can anyone help please

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browsers do not [submit the values of disabled controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355728/values-of-disabled-inputs-will-not-be-submited).  Create a hidden field that contains the value you want posted to your controller.