# jQuery form.submit event handler prevents MVC button action to be populated in model

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

There are weird things started to happen with the project I'm currently dealing with. I've already found an easy and convinient workaround, however I don't like the idea of touching the bulk amount of existing code as it would require a full regression test. So I've built a small app to reproduct the issue and still was able to do so. Here are some details:

There are several submit buttons on the single form, button value is used in ActionMethod to distinguish user actions. Everything works well - I get 'Create' and 'Update' in model Action field. Unless I put a jQuery handler on submit event - this time I'm starting to get 'Index' all the time. Actually the handler itself is still ok, but the single line that disables the submit button performs the magic.

Is anyone able to explain what happens here? Thanks in advance.

The page (Index.cshtml):

```
@model MvcButtonTest.Models.HomeData
<html>
<head>
<title>Index</title>
@System.Web.Optimization.Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("form").submit(function (ev) {
//          $(":submit", this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)<br />
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ID)
        <input name="Action" type="submit" value="Create" />
        <input name="Action" type="submit" value="Update" />
        <input name="Action" type="submit" value="Delete" />
    }     
</body>
</html>
```

Model HomeData.cs:

```
public class HomeData
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String Action { get; set; }
    public Int32 ID { get; set; }
}
```

Controller HomeController.cs:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(HomeData data)
    {
        // data.Action - check if it's Create or Delete
        return View();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That´s because disabled inputs [are not submitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355728/values-of-disabled-inputs-will-not-be-submited), so you are not sending the value of the button that was clicked.

As there is no "Action" parameter in the form data, MVC is using the action parameter of the route that matched the request, in this case your Index method. (If you rename the model property and input names as MyAction instead of Action, then you will see the value is null as no value is included in the response and the property name doesnt match any route segment).