# Disable input date but retrieve value

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to disable input date so that user can edit the current value in the input but i can not retrieve the value if i disable the input.

```
<form action="test123123.php" method="post">
<input type="date" name="datap"  value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>" disabled>
<input type="submit" name="ok">
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['ok'])){
echo $_POST['datap'];
}
```

This code returns the error that can not find 'datap' and i understand that it gives this error because can not see the input. How can i disable the input but be able to retrive value. The code above is just an example. I am interested on a general application not local.

Update:

i tryed with min and max in the same day but the user has to use the sliders to lock the chooce

Comment: Enable it just before submitting from `onsubmit` (and don't return `false` from that handler)

Comment: `readonly` instead of `disabled`?

Comment: Duplicate of [values of disabled inputs will not be submited?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355728/values-of-disabled-inputs-will-not-be-submited)

Answer (score 1):

Store the known good value in a hidden field:

```
<form action="test123123.php" method="post">
<input type="date" name="datap-input"  value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>" disabled>
<input type="hidden" name="datap"  value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>">
<input type="submit" name="ok">
</form>
```

As others have suggested, readonly may work for you, but the behavior and appearance of disabled and readonly inputs is different.  Readonly would be easier if it's appropriate for your use-case.

Answer (score 0):

[Disabled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input) element values are not passed with form submission, so use `readonly` instead, as:

```
<input type="date" name="datap"  value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>" readonly />
```