# DropDownListFor value empty after Postback to Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I develop a web application below ASP.NET MVC 4 with Razor Views.

I noticed now that `SomethingID` is *empty* in the ViewModel after Postback (to the Controller)
if I *only add* the `disabled` HTML attribute to DropDownListFor:

```
// SomethingID becomes 0:
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SomethingID, Model.SomethingList, new { @disabled = "disabled" })
```

It doesn't happen if I remove the `disabled` Attribute, SomethingID has the proper value then:

```
// SomethingID keeps its value (greater than 0):
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SomethingID, Model.SomethingList)
```

Has someone experienced that problem already?
At the moment, I try to solve the problem with jQuery, by storing the value in a HiddenFor field.

But my question would be: Is there a better solution? Is it intended behaviour from Microsoft that Dropdownlists shall forget everything as soon as they are disabled? Do I do a mistake? Is it a bug?

Remark: I have 5 Dropdownlists in my View, all 5 show the same behaviour.

Many thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Setting the input to disabled will prevent it from posting.  You can use `Readonly` rather than disabled. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355728/values-of-disabled-inputs-will-not-be-submited

Comment: Many thanks to you for the hint!!! I will try it.

Comment: Great!!! That solves my problem!!! Thanks a lot!!! :-)

Comment: Hi, I have to rework my last answer here. The readonly seemed to work first. But the debugging tool then told me that I still could select a value from the dropdownlist although it was readonly and that the new selected value was sent to the Controller then. I went the following way now: SomethingID is stored in a hidden field, and the text of Something is displayed in a readonly textbox now. I should have used textboxes in that special case earlier. LOL. I learned in that way...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quite simply the reason you are seeing this is because elements that have the disabled attribute do not have their values posted to the server. See this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7357256/disabled-form-inputs-do-not-appear-in-the-request) for more detail.

Comment: Many thanks for the fast answer! I have to wait some minutes before I can accept your answer.

Comment: You're welcome. You basically discovered this on your own by removed the `disabled` attribute and noticing the value was posted.