# pass value from $_GET to $_POST

Tags: php

So, I have a disabled email form field whose placeholder and value are retrieved from $_GET['email']:

```
<input name="email" type="text" placeholder="<?php if(isset($_GET['email'])) echo $_GET['email']; ?>" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['email'])) echo $_GET['email']; ?>" disabled>
```

When the user fills out the form, I was hoping that $_POST['email'] would have the email value, but it doesn't (it's empty). What am I missing/forgetting? Is there a clever way to pass this value along? Thanks!

Comment: post the whole form, or at least the `<form>` tag

Comment: i believe i do? i left the rest out but the above is sandwiched between <form action="register.php" method="post">*form fields and submit button*</form>

Comment: If your form method is post, change disabled to readonly! http://stackoverflow.com/a/36758818/2209876

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**change attribute disabled to readonly** because disabled not submit values..

```
<input name="email" type="text" placeholder="<?php if(isset($_GET['email'])) echo $_GET['email']; ?>" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['email'])) echo $_GET['email']; ?>" readonly>
```

Comment: more info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355728/values-of-disabled-inputs-will-not-be-submited

Comment: wonderful! that did the trick. thanks to others who said the same.

Answer (score 3):

As [Cuchu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36758771/pass-value-from-get-to-post/36758818#36758818) stated, you could use [readonly](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_readonly.asp) instead of disabled. Or you could duplicate the field and change the type to hidden.

```
<form method="post" action="register.php">
    <input type="text" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['email'])) echo $_GET['email']; ?>" disabled>
    <input name="email" type="hidden" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['email'])) echo $_GET['email']; ?>">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it is better to use the `readonly` attribute instead of disabling the input.

```
<input name="email" type="text" placeholder="<?php if(isset($_GET['email'])) echo $_GET['email']; ?>" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['email'])) echo $_GET['email']; ?>" readonly="readonly">
```

Comment: or you could add hidden input and then put the email value in it.

Answer (score 0):

Placeholder is a prompt, not a value.  If you want the textfield to have a value of the email, use the "value" attribute, not the "placeholder".

Answer (score 0):

You should enclose in a form tag and set the method to post as

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input name="email" type="text" placeholder="<?php if(isset($_GET['email'])) echo $_GET['email']; ?>" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['email'])) echo $_GET['email']; ?>" disabled>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  //try this
<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="email"><input type="submit" value="click" name="btnClick" id="btnClick">
<input type="text" name="email1" placeholder="inserted value" value="<?php echo (isset($_POST['email']))? $_POST['email'] : "" ?> ">      
</form>
```

Comment: <input type="text" name="email1" placeholder="inserted value" value="<?  php echo (isset($_POST['email']))? $_POST['email'] : "" ?> " disabled="disabled">   you can disable it so it can b edited,,inserted value only can be seen or use read only attribute.