# propagating a value from one route to another in flask

Tags: python, flask

So, 
  I am very new to flask and front end programming..

I have a form: like this

```
<form action="{{ url_for('search') }}" method="post">
    Showing values for: <input type="text" name="name" value={{ name }} disabled><br><br>
    <select name="movie" width="300px">
        {% for movie in movie_list %}
        <option value="{{ movie }}" SELECTED>{{ movie }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Recommend!!">
</form>
```

And this is how I am capturing in flask

```
@app.route('/web/search', methods=['post','get'])
def search():
    print request.method, request.form
```

So, you can see, that in html form.. I have two fields..

name (text box) which already have a default value set

and option_list

And, my intention is, when the user presses "submit", both these fields are 
received in backend

But the print statement shows..

```
POST ImmutableMultiDict([('movie', u'foobar')])
```

But I dont see the name field?

How do I fix this?

Comment: I don't think browsers include disabled fields in the request.

Comment: @dirn: So, i want to pass this name when the user submits a form.. whats a good way to capture this ?

Comment: If it needs to be visible, you can use `readonly`. Otherwise just make it hidden.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably because you're missing quotes around the `value` for the first `input`.

Also disabled inputs won't be passed, [values of disabled inputs will not be submited?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355728/values-of-disabled-inputs-will-not-be-submited)

Comment: I am actually not sure I understand?

Comment: the `value` attribute on the second line is missing quotes.

Comment: but how do i put quotes around it
value = " {{ name }} " ?

Comment: I did `<input type="text" name="name" value="{{ name }}" disabled><br><br>`
Didnt worked :(

Comment: Ah.. so how do i pass the value when user submits the form?

Answer (score 2):

You are allowing both `GET` and `POST` requests, but you don't differentiate between them in your code.  If you want to grab those values when the user submits them, then you need to do something when that form `POST`s.  Perhaps something like:

```
@app.route('/web/search/', methods=['POST','GET'])
def search():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print request.method, request.form
        # do some stuff
        return redirect(url_for('search_results', results=results))
    else:
        return render_template('my_template.html')
```

Then, in the `if` statement, you can do things with the variables.  In my imaginary case here, I'm sending the user to another web page where you can show the results of the search.  I just made up a template name for `render_template()`, so you can substitute in whatever your template is actually called.