# How to fetch selected data's value from disabled list in MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have designed a razor-view that is bounded with model. This page containing multiple lists(drop-down). In some case depended child drop-down list is disabled.
There is need to fetch it's value. Please help me for it.

Answer (score 2):

Disabled controls will not post their values back to the server-side, see [values of disabled inputs will not be submited?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355728/values-of-disabled-inputs-will-not-be-submited) for extra info.

If you want to access the value you will have to store (copy) it somewhere else, such as an extra `<input type="hidden"/>`

Answer (score 0):

There is need to include a hidden field with the same name and value

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.StateId, Model.States, new { disabled = "disabled" })
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.StateId)
```

1. When form is posted with MVC model then respective selected drop-down value will be sent with it.
2. In case you are posting the form with ajax post then- If drop-down is disabled dynamically with javascript then assign the currently selected value of the dropdown to the hidden field just after disabling it.