# JavaScript form validation is not submitting, page just reload

Tags: javascript, validation

I have a small form that i want to validate and disable submit button to prevent multiple entries being added to the database.

I just check that Firstname and Lastname are at leat 2 characters and Second disable the button on form submit.

**The only problem now is that it doesn't submit the form it just reload the page.**

my code is:

```js
function disableButton() {
  /*disable button after form submit*/

  var imgFirstname = document.getElementById('imgFname');
  var imgLastname = document.getElementById('imgLname');

  var firstname = document.forms['form']['txtFname'];
  var lastname = document.forms['form']['txtLname'];
  var errors = 0;

  if (firstname.value.length < 2) {
    firstname.style.border = "1px solid #f50303";
    imgFirstname.src = "images/error.png";
    errors++;
  } else {
    firstname.style.border = "1px solid #06be15";
    imgFirstname.src = "images/success.png";
  }

  if (lastname.value.length < 2) {
    lastname.style.border = "1px solid #f50303";
    imgLastname.src = "images/error.png";
    errors++;
  } else {
    lastname.style.border = "1px solid #06be15";
    imgLastname.src = "images/success.png";
  }

  firstname.addEventListener('blur', fNameVerify, true);
  lastname.addEventListener('blur', lNameVerify, true);

  function fNameVerify() {
    if (firstname.value.length > 1) {
      firstname.style.border = "1px solid #06be15";
      imgFirstname.src = "images/success.png";
    } else {
      firstname.style.border = "1px solid #f50303";
      imgFirstname.src = "images/error.png";
    }
  }

  function lNameVerify() {
    if (lastname.value.length > 1) {
      lastname.style.border = "1px solid #06be15";
      imgLastname.src = "images/success.png";
    } else {
      lastname.style.border = "1px solid #f50303";
      imgLastname.src = "images/error.png";
    }
  }

  if (errors == 0) {
    // document.getElementById("idBtnAdd").disabled = true;
    document.forms["form"].submit();
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<form name='form' onsubmit='return disableButton();' method='post'>
  <label for='idFirstname'>First Name:*</label>
  <input id='idFirstname' type='text' name='txtFname'>
  <img id='imgFname' src='images/transparent.png'>

  <label for='idLastname'>Last Name:*</label>
  <input id='idLastname' type='text' name='txtLname'>
  <img id='imgLname' src='images/transparent.png'>

  <label for='idPhone'>Phone (Optional):</label>
  <input id='idPhone' type='text' name='telPhone'>
  <img id='imgPhone-error' src='images/transparent.png'>
  <button id='idBtnAdd' type='submit' name='btnAdd'>Add Client!</button>
</form>
```

Comment: There's no need to call `document.forms["form"].submit()`, since returning `true` will submit the form.

Comment: i added in the hope of making it work but without document.forms["form"].submit() is STILL does not work. page just reload if validation rerturn true

Comment: You don't have an `action` attribute in the form, so submitting the form sends to the same URL as the original page, which will just reload it if there's no script there.

Comment: You've not specified `action` parameter. Do you intend to submit it to the page itself? if so, whats wrong with it?

Comment: Yes, correct i'm posting to the same page. and then will take care of the data with php if (isset($_POST['btnAdd'])){ and so on

Comment: `$_POST['btnAdd']` won't be set if you call `.submit()`. Buttons are only included in the post when during normal form submission from clicking that button.

Comment: What does `var_dump($_POST)` show when the form gets submitted?

Comment: Thank you @Barmar. back to discussion.  Why dont you change `'#btnAdd'` type to `input`? Then it will simply be sent regardless of your submission model.

Comment: @barmar it display "array(3) { ["txtFname"]=> string(4) "test" ["txtLname"]=> string(4) "test" ["telPhone"]=> string(0) "" }"

Comment: i see btnAdd is not submitted along the $_POST array, i wonder why

Comment: @wilson382 why dont you change btnAdd to `<input type='submit' ... />` ?

Comment: @wilson382 Did you get rid of `document.forms["form"].submit()`? I explained why that prevent sending `btnAdd`.

Comment: @Behrad Khodayar tried it, no vail yet

Comment: @barmar yes I commented

Comment: I just tested the code you've provided in question, and I get this by var_dump($_POST); `array(4) { ["txtFname"]=> string(4) "asdf" ["txtLname"]=> string(5) "sasdf" ["telPhone"]=> string(0) "" ["btnAdd"]=> string(0) "" }`

Comment: @wilson382 Sorry I'm asking, but sometimes it even occurs to myself. So dont take it personally, Are you considering case-sensitivity in PHP ?

Comment: @BehradKhodayar Yes, indeed this is my php condition `if (isset($_POST['btnAdd'])){ //server side validation and rest of code }`

Comment: There is nothing wrong with my code, i separeted my code in this question from my whole application and it works.

Comment: never mind i accicently comment the line thet disable the button. back to the same problem

Comment: if this line is commented `document.getElementById("idBtnAdd").disabled = true;` it works, if i un-comment it then button does not get submit it to $_POST()

Comment: Its by design. Hidden elements of a form, will not be posted. Check this out: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355728/values-of-disabled-inputs-will-not-be-submited#answer-1355734>

Comment: @wilson as a workaround on this, you can add a hidden input/button to your form, & check forms submission by help of that element. e.g. `if(isset($_POST['newElem'})`

Comment: ohh it makes. The button doesnt get submitted because is being disabled before the form submit.

Comment: @BehradKhodayar that solved the problem.

Comment: Glad to hear that. Keep going. I'll update the answers as a record here to stay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `action` attribute specified for form. So nothing is wrong with result you get.

---

### UPDATE

Because you say its intentionally that the page is form's target(action) itself, so not including the `action` attribute is not the problem.

The bug that `#btnAdd` doesn't get posted, arises because **Disabled elements are not posted by browsers & its by design.** Check this out for more info: [values of disabled inputs will not be submited?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355728/values-of-disabled-inputs-will-not-be-submited#answer-1355734)

There are 2 workarounds for this:

- Create a hidden element with the same name/value and disable the visible element only(You can achieve this with the help of jquery's `$(":visible")` or `not(":hidden")` selectors). This way the hidden active element will be posted as desired.
- Add a hidden input/button to your form, & check forms submission by help of that element. e.g. `if(isset($_POST['newElem'}){...}`

Comment: He said in a comment that he's submitting to the same page, and the PHP script checks the input. So this isn't the problem.