# Submitting a form only after filling a field in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm building a Vue app. When I click the button in the form I want to fill the input with value `paypal` and then submit the form. But from `test_form.php` (it's the file action of the form) the variable `$_POST['paymentMethod']` contains `null` instead of `paypal`! Where I'm wrong?

Here is the code I'm using:

HTML:

```
<form action="test/test_form.php" method="POST" ref="form">
  <button type="button" v-on:click="setMethod('cc')">Credit card</button>
  <button type="button" v-on:click="setMethod('paypal')">Paypal</button>
  <input type="text" name="paymentMethod" required v-model="selectedMethod">
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",

  data: {
    selectedMethod: null,
  },

  methods: {

    // Set payment
    setMethod: function(type) {
      this.selectedMethod = type; // Here I fill the field
      this.$refs.form.submit(); // Then I submit the form
    },
  }

});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using Vue's [nextTick](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick) method to defer your form post until *after* the DOM has been updated:

```
  if (type == 'paypal'){
    var me = this;
    Vue.nextTick(function() {
        me.$refs.form.submit();
    });
  }
```

Comment: I just removed the readonly attribute but the problem persists. I updated the question to make it more clear.

Comment: Thanks Patrick! I suggest you to remove the first part of your answer because it's wrong => https://stackoverflow.com/a/16438237/1252920