# In Html5 how do I renable an input field when the user submits the form

Tags: javascript

In Html5 how do I renable an input field when the user submits the form.I have a text field that user can only modify using some associted button so I set it to disabled so they cannot modify it manually. But because it is disabled when user submits the form my server does not receive the value of the field in request. So how do I make it enabled just as submit button pressed, or is there another approach I should take.

Comment: One way is to take the value and put it into a type="hidden" input in the submit event.

Comment: A field being disabled doesn't stop it from being submitted. Where's your code?

Comment: `form.submit = function () { field.disabled = false; }`?

Comment: @SterlingArcher Well, [according to HTML 4, disabled fields should not be submitted with the form](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1355734/215552), and indeed HTML5 has kept up the tradition, using the phrase "The disabled attribute is used to make the control non-interactive and to prevent its value from being submitted." everywhere the disabled attribute is mentioned.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan no kidding? Well, I stand corrected then, thank you for the knowledge!

Comment: seems the solution is to use readonly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`disabled` elements do not send its value when form submitted, you should use `readonly` instead.

According to [w3c's definition](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.12):

> **Disabled:**
>
> - When set for a form control, this boolean attribute disables the control for user input.
> - Disabled controls do not receive focus.
> - Disabled controls are skipped in tabbing navigation.
> - Disabled controls cannot be successful.
>
> **Readonly:**
>
> - When set for a form control, this boolean attribute prohibits changes to the control.
> - Read-only elements receive focus but cannot be modified by the user.
> - Read-only elements are included in tabbing navigation.
> - Read-only elements may be successful.

**EDIT:** You can apply CSS rules for visual indication.

```css
[readonly] {
  cursor: not-allowed;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #555;  
}
```

```html
<label>Not "Disabled"</label>
<br>
<input type="text">
<br>
<br>
<label>"Disabled" (Actually readonly)</label>
<br>
<input type="text" readonly>
<br>
<br>
<label>You can still select (therefore copy) readonly values</label>
<br>
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" readonly>Hello :)</textarea>
```

Comment: Thankyou that works, the only negaive is that unlike a disabled field it doesnt give much visual indication that it is read only (at reast on Firefox)

Comment: @PaulTaylor Updated my answer so you can add visual indication for readonly inputs

Comment: thanks but do you know how to change the appearance of the input field itself so it looks more like disabled box ?

Comment: @PaulTaylor updated snippet. Hope it suit your needs.