# Retrieve data from textfield elements created dynamically with Django templates

Tags: python, django, forms, templates, view

I have a Django view like this:

```
def viewA(request):
    if request.POST.get('Go'):
       # Get all fields
       all = {}
       for key, values in request.POST.lists():
           all[key]=values
       print (all)
```

With this html:

```
<label>Numero de telefono</label>
<input type="text" name="phone" autocomplete="off"/>
<input type="submit" name="Go" value="Send">
```

When i click 'Go' button, i get "all" dict with the phone value inside. Ok.

My problem is that i have another view where i create input elements with a template like this:

```
<div>
    {% for table, campos in tables.items %}
        <div class="taable">
            <label>{{table}}</label>
                {% for campo in campos %}
                    <div class="caampo">
                        <input type="text" value="{{campo}}" disabled name="{{table}}:{{campo}}"/>
                        <select>
                            <option>Varchar</option>
                            <option>Int</option>
...
```

In this case, when i click 'Go' button don't retrieve the data for this elements created dynamically with django template.
How can I get this?

Thanks!

Comment: In your view you are first accessing `request.GET` and later `request.POST`. Try changing it to use the same both times.

Comment: if you post the whole form html, maybe we can help, the bug can be not in the shortcodes that you have posted

Comment: @Ralf sorry! It was a mistake when i put code here. In my view i use POST in the both times...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabled inputs are not submitted in POST requests.

```
# your input elements
<input type="text" value="{{campo}}" disabled name="{{table}}:{{campo}}"/>
```

Remove the `disabled` attribute from the inputs.

Maybe you could use `readonly` instead. See also these related questions:

1. [Disabled form inputs do not appear in the request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7357256/disabled-form-inputs-do-not-appear-in-the-request)
2. [values of disabled inputs will not be submitted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355728/values-of-disabled-inputs-will-not-be-submitted/)