# Undefined index error messsage

Tags: php, oop

I'm working with PHP to make a Blogging CMS. So here is my code:

```
if(isset($_POST['insert_blog'])){
    $blog_id = uniqid('blog_post');
    $blog_author = $_POST['blog_author'];
    $blog_title = $_POST['blog_title'];
    $blog_body = $_POST['blog_body'];
    $blog_tags = $_POST['blog_tags'];
    $blog_category = $_POST['blog_category'];

    if($blog_title == '' OR $blog_body == ''  OR $blog_tags == ''){
        echo "
            <script>alert('Please fill all the fields!')</script>
            exit();
        ";
    }else{
        $insert_blog = "
            INSERT INTO `blogs` (`blog_id`,`blog_author`,`blog_title`,`blog_body`,`blog_category`,`blog_tags`,`date_posting`) 
            VALUES ('$blog_id','$blog_author','$blog_title','$blog_body','$blog_category','$blog_tags',NOW())
        ";
        $run_blog = mysqli_query($con2,$insert_blog);
        if($run_blog){
            echo "<META HTTP-EQUIV='Refresh' Content='0; URL=blognew-homepage.php?blog_id=$blog_id'>";
        }else{
            error_reporting(E_ALL);
            die(mysqli_error($con2));
        }
    }
}
```

And I get this error:

```
Undefined index: blog_author on line 5
```

Which basically gets the value of this input from the form:

```
<input class="form-control input-sm" type="text" disabled="disabled" name="blog_author" value="author: <?php echo $dataSet->GetUsername(); ?>">
```

So as you can see I have set the `$dataSet` variable to a method of class which simply gets the username of Admin.

And the other variables passed in manually by user in the form.

(Because they're working fine no need to mention them here)

So why am I getting this error message? Is it wrong to include a method in this form? How to fix this issue?

Comment: I think you are send data through HTML form.  you can easy check which input data send in server use this command <?php  print_r($_POST); ?>. If your blog_author data get it is ok.

Comment: `disabled="disabled"` ???? If you disable an element it will NOT be available in the POSTed data

Comment: Possible duplicate of [values of disabled inputs will not be submitted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355728/values-of-disabled-inputs-will-not-be-submitted)

Comment: You should be using prepared statements, with that code you're vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input is `disabled`, what means that the value from that input will not appear in `$_POST`. If you want to use the disabled attribute, you can rename the disabled input and add a hidden input with the correct name/value like this:

```
<input class="form-control input-sm" type="text" disabled="disabled" name="blog_author_disabled" value="author: <?php echo $dataSet->GetUsername(); ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="blog_author" value="author: <?php echo $dataSet->GetUsername(); ?>">
```

Or you can replace the `disabled` attribute with `readonly`:

```
<input class="form-control input-sm" type="text" readonly name="blog_author_disabled" value="author: <?php echo $dataSet->GetUsername(); ?>">
```

This way the value will not be editable, but it will appear in `$_POST`.