# 400 Bad Request: KeyError:

Tags: python, mysql, database, flask

I am trying to create an online book store. I really can't figure out what's wrong in this code. It shows the following error:

`werkzeug.exceptions.HTTPException.wrap.<locals>.newcls: 400 Bad Request: KeyError: 'roomno'`

```
@app.route('/order_book',methods=['GET','POST'])
def order_book():
    if not session.get('logged_in'):
        return render_template('user_login.html')
    user_id=session['userid']
    cur=connection.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM address WHERE user_id=%s",[user_id])
    addr_data=cur.fetchone()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        book_id = request.form['book_id1']
    if not addr_data:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            room_no = request.form['roomno']
            building = request.form['building']
            street = request.form['street']
            city = request.form['city']
            zipcode = request.form['zipcode']
            cur.execute("INSERT INTO address(user_id,room_no,building,street,city,zipcode) VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)",(userid,room_no,building,street,city,zipcode))
            connection.commit()
            print('Address Added')
            return redirect(url_for('order_book'))
        return render_template('address.html')
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM books WHERE book_id=%s",[book_id])
    book_data=cur.fetchone()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM login WHERE user_id=%s",[user_id])
    cust_data=cur.fetchone()
    cur.close()
    print(cust_data)
    print(addr_data)
    print(book_data)
    return render_template('order_book.html',addr_data=addr_data,book_data=book_data,cust_data=cust_data)
```

html code

`order.html`

```
<html>  
<h1>PLACE ORDER</h1><br>



            <h5><a class="card-title" id="" href="">{{ books_data[0] }}</a></h5>
            <h4>{{ books_data[1] }}</h4>
            <span>{{ books_data[2] }}</span>
        

<form action="placeorder" method="POST">
  <div class="nav-link">
  <div class="form-group">
    Room no<br><input type="text" name="roomno"  value={{ addr_data[2] }} disabled><br><br>
    building<br><input type="text" name="building"  value={{ addr_data[3] }} disabled><br><br>
    street<br><input type="text" name="street"  value={{ addr_data[4] }} disabled><br><br>
    city<br><input type="text" name="city"  value={{ addr_data[5] }} disabled><br><br>
    zipcode<br><input type="text" name="zipcode"  value={{ addr_data[6] }} disabled><br><br>
    Mobilenumber<br><input type="text" name="phoneno"  value={{ cust_data[4] }} disabled><br><br>
    Email<br><input type="text" name="emailids"  value={{ cust_data[3] }} disabled><br><br>
<input type="text" name="book_id"  value={{ book_data[1] }} style="display:none">
<input type="text" name="user_id"  value={{ cust_data[0] }} style="display:none">
 <input type="text" name="book_price"  value={{ book_data[8] }} style="display:none">
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Place Order">
</form>
</div>
</div>
</html>
```

I have tried to change the html page and I have tried db changes. I don't know what to do.

Comment: Hi, please add the error also and modify the title of the question

Comment: `request.form['roomno']` - in this line `roomno` is the key of a dictionary. My guess is it isn't being POSTed.

Comment: i've added at the question

Comment: Since this is Python, why don't you print the contents of `request.form` to see what data actually exists.

Comment: roomno is the value i get from the customer

Comment: i'm getting data from the user actually no data exist

Comment: If no data exists then you have an error in your HTML. You should post that here too.

Comment: i have added that too

Comment: That portion ended up being essential. Disabled inputs are not part of POST parameters. I provided an answer to give a bit more insight.

Comment: Partly unrelated but : __NEVER EVER__ trust user inputs, __ALWAYS__ sanitize and validate them before use. That's what WTForms are for (http://exploreflask.com/en/latest/forms.html)

Comment: you have to get address from the user bruh!!! not your own @bruno desthuilliers

Answer (score 0):

The issue is your input fields are marked as disabled. Disabled inputs will not be POSTed. See [Values of disabled inputs will not be submitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355728/values-of-disabled-inputs-will-not-be-submitted) for more information. A few workarounds are to instead use `readonly="readonly"` or `<input type="hidden">`, depending on if you want users to see the inputs or not. You could also remove the disabled tag via JavaScript on submission of the form. Doing any of those things should result in your input values being POSTed correctly and the your Flask backend should then receive the data.