# Model arrives empty at controller when input is disabled

Tags: forms, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

In my form, I have two inputs which are disabled, as the user has to fill them with a keyboard I made on the view. However, when I submit the form, the object arrives with its parameters at 0 (as they are numbers).  I know that its the disable tag which makes it happens because when I delete the tag, the values are initialized.

these are my inputs:

```
 <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Cliente, new { htmlAttributes = new { disabled = "true" } })</td>
```

How could I disable them and at the same time send the values to the controller?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `readonly` attribute instead of `disabled`.

disabled form elements are not submitted to post request.
[Reference1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355728/values-of-disabled-inputs-will-not-be-submitted)
[Reference2](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_readonly.asp)