# When i put disabled attribute in html input tag asp.net-core mvc not mapping it

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

#### Scenario:

This is bizarre for me right now.. When I submit form to controller all input fields are mapped correctly, but this:

```
<input asp-for="Id" disabled class="form-control" value="something"/>
```

wont (always null).

#### The problem is:

when i remove disabled works perfectly!

I have another page with similar disabled input field and that page works fine. What happening here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The **disabled** attribute for  element in HTML is used to specify that the input field is disabled. A disabled input is un-clickable and unusable. It is a boolean attribute. The [disabled  elements](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_disabled.asp) are not submitted in the form.

You could use **readonly** instead of **disabled**

```
<input asp-for="Id" readonly class="form-control" value="[something]" />
```

Reference : https://stackoverflow.com/a/1355734/10201850

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to pass a default value if disabled? I'm not sure what are you trying to pass but try specifying the value attribute in your input, like:

```
<input asp-for="Id" disabled class="form-control" value="[something]" />
```

Comment: I forgot to put value.. Value is present.. I sad, when remove disabled value is passed to controler

Answer (score 0):

If your Input Field values coming from another page or database use "readonly".