# Text Input Values set by jQuery are not able to POST

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with action method POST. Some Controls in php which are being calculated in jQuery. All the form control values are accessible in next form using POST. But the values I am adding through jQuery are not posting to next form. Please help.

My Form Control Part:

```js
$('#vipcount, #vipprice').keyup(function() {
  var value1 = parseFloat($('#vipcount').val()) || 0;
  var value2 = parseFloat($('#vipprice').val()) || 0;
  var days = parseFloat($('#days').val()) || 0;
  gtotal1 = (value1 * value2) * days;
  gCount1 = value1;
  var value3 = addCommas(gtotal1.toFixed(2)); //(value1 * value2).toFixed(2);
  var value4 = value3 + ' AED';
  //$('#viptotal').val(value4);
  //alert($('#viptotal').val());
  $('#viptotal').text(value4);
  document.getElementsByName("viptotal")[0].value = value4;
  footerFill(gtotal1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-12">
  <fieldset>
    <h5>VIP Meals Total<small class="text-muted"> </small></h5>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input id="viptotal" class="form-control date-inputmask" type="text" placeholder="0.00 AED" disabled=true name="viptotal" />
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

Part of Code to display this value is like this:

```
$message .= '<td style="width:35%">' . $_POST['viptotal'] . '</td>';
```

I don't know where I am wrong.

Comment: Where is your `#viptotal` field in your HTML? I notice you're changing the `text()` attribute, but not the actual `val()` of that field, so that's almost certainly part of your problem.

Comment: 1. Not PHP related. 2: JScript was a MS only scripting language, you mean jQuery. 3. Please click edit, scroll down and click edit above snippet and update the snippet I made you to be a [mcve] - PS: [Browsers do not forward disabled fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355728/values-of-disabled-inputs-will-not-be-submitted)

Comment: Also please use jQuery when you have it: `$("[name=viptotal]").val(value4) ` or just  `$('#viptotal').val(value4);` - input fields do not have .text()

Comment: Dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355728/values-of-disabled-inputs-will-not-be-submitted

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Values of disabled inputs will not be submitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355728/values-of-disabled-inputs-will-not-be-submitted)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your code have a disabled=" true" for the input field. 
If the input field is disabled, Request doesn't include the value of the input field. 
you can add the readonly="readonly" instead of disabled=true.
And I can not see the input field with an id called "viptotal".

```
<input id="viptotal" class="form-control date-inputmask" type="text" placeholder="0.00 AED" readonly="readonly" name="viptotal" />
```

Comment: just pasted wrong para of code. I have edited it.

Comment: please copy the code . It will work.

Comment: Thanks a lot @He Zhi Yong It worked well.