# Request contains null although the input has been entered

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to update my data with Laravel. I'm able to create, read, delete the data but somehow i cannot update my data. I already checked my controller,model,route and view but i don't think there's any typo or anything. It only redirects to it's index page without being updated although i have entered new input. There's no error message at all so i checked where is the problem. So i checked my update function in my controller and tried to show the request by `echo "$request->kode_kontak";` and `echo $request->kode_kontak;` but it shows nothing which i assume that it's null/empty but when i `echo "yes"` it showed on the screen "yes" i tested this because i want to know if the function itself is working so the problem here is that the request contains null, no wonder i cannot update it. Why is the request isn't passed? why is it like this? and how to fix it?

**Route for edit and update**

```
Route::get('contact/{contact}/edit', 'ContactController@edit')->name('contact.edit');
Route::patch('contact/{contact}','ContactController@update')->name('contact.update');
```

**Controller with edit and update function**

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Contact;
use DB;

public function edit($kode_kontak){
        $contact = DB::table('contact')->where('kode_kontak',$kode_kontak)->get();
        return view('contact.edit',['contact' => $contact]);
    }

public function update(Request $request){
        DB::table('contact')->where('kode_kontak',$request->kode_kontak)->update([
            'email' => $request->email,
            'telepon' => $request->telepon,
        ]);
        return redirect('contact');
    }
```

**Model**

```
class Contact extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;
    
    protected $table = 'contact';

    protected $fillable = [
        'kode_kontak',
        'kode_pegawai',
        'email',
        'telepon'
        
    ];

    protected $primaryKey = 'kode_kontak';
}
```

**View of edit.blade.php**

```
<div id="contact">
    <h2>Edit Contact</h2>
    @foreach($contact as $p)
        <form action="{{ route('contact.update', ['kode_pegawai' => $p->kode_pegawai]) }}" method="POST">
    @csrf
    @method('patch')
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="kode_contact" class="control-label">Kode Kontak</label>
            <input type="text" name="kode_kontak" id="kode_kontak" class="form-control" value="{{ $p->kode_kontak}}" disabled>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="kode_pegawai" class="control-label">Kode Pegawai</label>
            <input type="text" name="kode_pegawai" id="kode_pegawai" class="form-control" value="{{ $p->kode_pegawai}}" disabled>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email" class="control-label">Email</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" value="{{ $p->email}}">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="telepon" class="control-label">Telepon</label>
            <input type="text" name="telepon" id="telepon" class="form-control" value="{{ $p->telepon}}">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="btn btn-primary form-control" type="submit" value="Simpan">
        </div>
    </form>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

Comment: Can you share a dd($request->all()) please.

Comment: this is happening for `patch` in laravel patch is a part of resouece routr , you can solve it by `post` request. change patch to post

Comment: Thanks to that `@foreach` there could be many duplicated ids in the html.

Comment: @KurtFriars it shows `array:3 [▼
  "_token" => "b30FL4q5RrPyNqV8glt9YhK6WBBGbtDvlG93DE6L"
  "email" => "aya@gmail.com"
  "telepon" => "087885768574"
]`

Comment: I got the problem, in request you have `_token` , `email`, `telepon`, but you not have `kode_kontak` then how can you update?

Comment: but whats wrong in your code? delete disabled or `$request->kode_kontak` to `$contact` ?

Comment: i'm sorry it's my fault, after i did what @KurtFriars said, i did not refresh properly, i'm so sorry for my clumsiness

Comment: but how do you get `kode_kontak` id?

Comment: @STA by removing the disabled on the input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that you have disabled those inputs. [Disabled inputs will not be submitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355728/values-of-disabled-inputs-will-not-be-submitted).

If you want to display the disabled inputs, but still PATCH the values, you will need to add hidden inputs with those values like:

```
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="kode_contact" class="control-label">Kode Kontak</label>
            <input type="text" id="kode_kontak" class="form-control" value="{{ $p->kode_kontak}}" disabled>
            <input type="hidden" name="kode_kontak" value="{{ $p->kode_kontak}}">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="kode_pegawai" class="control-label">Kode Pegawai</label>
            <input type="text" id="kode_pegawai" class="form-control" value="{{ $p->kode_pegawai}}" disabled>
            <input type="hidden" name="kode_pegawai" value="{{ $p->kode_pegawai}}">
        </div>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: @potatostudent For debugging purposes try removing the disabled property on the inputs and submit, then inspect the request. If the values are still missing I will delete my answer.

Comment: I am going to leave this here, since I am quite confident this is related/the root cause of your issue. You have 2 disabled inputs not submitting their values (which they shouldn't), and two non-disabled inputs that are submitting their values.

Comment: @Kurt, `$kode_kontak` is not available on dd

Comment: @STA what about in network inspect request body? I will start trying to debug locally too

Comment: @KurtFriars but i still need to show the value of `kode_kontak` because i need to know which `kode` or `id` that i'm editing

Comment: @potatostudent So the it works when you remove disabled from the text inputs, but not when you use the hidden input approach?

Comment: @KurtFriars what you said works for me, exactly what you said

Comment: @potatostudent Ok, I just want to confirm, since we may be having English issues here, this answer completely solves your issue?

Answer (score 1):

`$request->kode_kontak` is `$contact` here, `$request->kode_kontak` is not available in `$request`, change `$contact` instead :

```
public function update(Request $request, $contact){
   DB::table('contact')->where('kode_kontak',$contact)->update([
      'email' => $request->email,
      'telepon' => $request->telepon,
   ]);
  return redirect('contact');
}
```